# How is it possible for a pot of meat to become pareve?

Tags: riddle, kashrut-kosher, food, meat, dairy

I was recently posed the following puzzle:

You have a pot of meat. You put in milk. It becomes [pareve](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_Pareve). How can this be?

Any ideas on how this is possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [Ohr Sameyach's archive, #156:](http://ohr.edu/ask/riddle.htm)

Mix 1 fluid ounce of beef gravy with 59 fluid ounces of water.  We don't have 1:60 yet, so the pot is "meaty."  Then pour in 1 fluid ounce milk.  The pot now contains 60:1 against the milk, but also 60:1 against the meat.  It's therefore pareve.

Compared to my previous answer:

-- Both answers only work if there are no recognizable pieces of meat.
  -- This answer is better in that the milk is "normal" milk.
  -- This answer is also better in that the pot is really, really pareve (human milk, while pareve after-the-fact, should not be used to cook with meat, as it looks really weird!)
  -- The previous answer is better as the only ingredients are in fact "meat" and "milk"; not "very dilute meaty substance."

Comment: Are you allowed to do this? Or would this count as a problem of אין מבטלין איסור לכתחילה?

Comment: Yes you'd be allowed to do so; at no point was there a pot of "issur" that you diluted. You took one thing that was 100% kosher (albeit dairy) and added another that was 100% kosher (albeit meat).

Comment: You have a meat mixture and you are intentionally adding milk to it. When the first drop of milk hits the meat mixture, you are nullifying it l'chatchila, no?

Comment: Nope. The prohibition is to take something that is right now non-kosher, and add something to it. Pot A is kosher, Pot B is kosher.

Comment: @Shalom: that's true for any basar b'chalav case. The point is that you are adding a drop of milk to a meat mixture, which is forbidden. Then you continue to add milk so that the mixture is no longer meat. But I don't understand how you are allowed to add the first drop of milk to a meat mixture?

Comment: If you look at Ohr Sameach's answer, you will see they are talking about how does one "have" such a mixture, not "make" such a mixture. They don't say "mix", rather they say "falls in". So your "recipe" is, I think, ossur. If you disagree, find a source to allow it.

Comment: I don't understand how this works based on this: http://www.etzion.org.il/vbm/archive/yomyom/r/r1.php

Comment: Start with this case: 1 fluid ounce of milk falls into 60 ounces of beef broth. Everything's kosher. Chana"n means "if the mixture is prohibited, we treat its entire volume as prohibited." Same thing here; 1 ounce milk falls into 60 ounces of very, very weak beef broth. You are correct, if you change the order, e.g. mix 1 ounce milk with 1 ounce meat and *then* 59 ounces water, you'd have 61 ounces of non-kosher. (This actually came up in regards to a product involving clam juice made on the same line as beer; the solution was to change the order in which ingredients were mixed.)

Answer (score 4):

If the milk was halachically pareve to begin with (e.g. human milk), and you added 60:1 by volume against the meat, the result would be pareve.

Comment: Would that help if there are recognizable peices of meat?

Comment: No, it wouldn't.  This assumes everything became a mush, or the meat was liquid to begin with, or something.