# Shnayim Veshishim - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows sixty-two?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point in the next few days, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Comment: Prev: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2145/17423

Comment: Next: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2184/shelosha-veshishim-mi-yodeya?r=SearchResults

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Bnai Yisrael had 62  consecutive years of peace following the subjugation of Moav by Ehud ben Gera.  Shoftim 4:30 says that (following the victory) the land was calm for 80 years.  Both the Ralbag and the Metzudas David in the name of the Seder Olam say that these years include the years that the Bnai Yisrael were subjugated by Moav, which was 18 (ibid. 14).  That leaves 62 of actual peace.

Comment: 3:30 is my girsa.

Answer (score 5):

62 are the descendants of Oved Edom the Gittite: his wife and each of his eight daughters-in-law all bore healthy sextuplets. (So 6 babies each for 9 women, plus his original 8 sons = 62.)

This was a special blessing from Hashem, in reward for his having hosted the Aron Hakodesh (Ark of the Covenant) in his house for three months, and treating it respectfully.

(Berachos 63b-64a, based on II Sam. 6:10-11 and I Chron. 26:5,8)

Comment: Did none of them have children?

Comment: They probably did, but those children aren't listed, so we don't know how many of them there were. It's also possible that subsequent generations of that family had a normal fertility rate, and that therefore there's no particular reason to mention it.

Answer (score 1):

[Bereishis Rabbah 53:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Bereishit_Rabbah.53.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) - Yehoshua killed 62 kings all of whom had been at the feast of Avraham. The Midrash questions were there not 31 at the feast? Thus, Yehoshua killed each king along with his commander-in-chief thereby making 62 leaders in all.

> דְּאָמַר רַבִּי יְהוֹשֻׁעַ בֶּן מְנַחֲמָה אוֹתָן שִׁשִּׁים וּשְׁנַיִם מְלָכִים שֶׁהָרַג יְהוֹשֻׁעַ כֻּלָּם הָיוּ בַּמִּשְׁתֶּה שֶׁל אַבְרָהָם אָבִינוּ, וְלֹא שְׁלשִׁים וְאֶחָד הָיוּ, אֶלָּא כִּי הַהִיא דְּאָמַר רַבִּי בֶּרֶכְיָה וְרַבִּי חֶלְבּוֹ וְרַבִּי פַּרְנָךְ מִשּׁוּם רַבִּי יוֹחָנָן (הושע יב, ט): מֶלֶךְ יְרִיחוֹ אֶחָד, מַה תַּלְמוּד לוֹמַר אֶחָד, אֶלָּא הוּא וְאַנְטְקֵיסוֹר שֶׁלּוֹ.

Answer (score 0):

And after those sixty-two weeks, the anointed one will disappear and vanish. Daniel 9:26.
I heard this is referring to High Priest Alexander Yannai.

https://jewsforjudaism.org/knowledge/articles/anointed-one-that-shall-be-cut-off