# What is the longest masechta?

Tags: talmud-gemara, statistics

I heard that Bava Basra is the longest masechta in blatt but Brochos is the longest mesechta in words. Did anyone else hear anything about that?

Comment: https://seforimblog.com/2023/03/the-longest-masechta-is/

Answer (score 42):

What most likely got this rumor started is that Brachos does have and lots of pages with minimal commentary.  Brachos does in fact (according to my calculations) take the record for *most Talmudic text **per page***.

| words/daf | letters/daf | words | letters | daf | mesechta |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1,115.14 | 4,337.46 | 70,254 | 273,260 | 63 | ברכות |
| 975.11 | 3,786.44 | 26,328 | 102,234 | 27 | כריתות |
| 971.69 | 3,771.92 | 12,632 | 49,035 | 13 | הוריות |
| 933.52 | 3,718.42 | 28,939 | 115,271 | 31 | מגילה |
| 931.76 | 3,625.12 | 104,357 | 406,013 | 112 | סנהדרין |
| 889.70 | 3,536.23 | 26,691 | 106,087 | 30 | תענית |
| 805.50 | 3,204.36 | 22,554 | 89,722 | 28 | מועד קטן |
| 815.60 | 3,179.48 | 39,149 | 152,615 | 48 | סוטה |
| 751.97 | 2,972.61 | 24,815 | 98,096 | 33 | ערכין |
| 765.57 | 2,947.04 | 17,608 | 67,782 | 23 | מכות |
| 729.62 | 2,866.87 | 113,820 | 447,232 | 156 | שבת |
| 731.56 | 2,859.64 | 59,256 | 231,631 | 81 | קידושין |
| 712.81 | 2,827.15 | 18,533 | 73,506 | 26 | חגיגה |
| 715.04 | 2,800.14 | 84,375 | 330,417 | 118 | בבא מציעא |
| 711.64 | 2,782.31 | 83,973 | 328,313 | 118 | בבא קמא |
| 691.35 | 2,762.51 | 51,851 | 207,188 | 75 | עבודה זרה |
| 698.94 | 2,760.97 | 23,065 | 91,112 | 33 | תמורה |
| 696.08 | 2,738.49 | 50,118 | 197,171 | 72 | נידה |
| 698.23 | 2,729.91 | 84,486 | 330,319 | 121 | יבמות |
| 687.53 | 2,724.15 | 23,376 | 92,621 | 34 | ראש השנה |
| 686.13 | 2,704.34 | 82,335 | 324,521 | 120 | פסחים |
| 683.51 | 2,684.79 | 60,832 | 238,946 | 89 | גיטין |
| 676.45 | 2,668.62 | 40,587 | 160,117 | 60 | בכורות |
| 681.60 | 2,660.13 | 32,717 | 127,686 | 48 | שבועות |
| 671.59 | 2,648.57 | 73,203 | 288,694 | 109 | מנחות |
| 661.24 | 2,602.73 | 73,398 | 288,903 | 111 | כתובות |
| 657.24 | 2,592.09 | 57,180 | 225,512 | 87 | יומא |
| 646.52 | 2,540.40 | 67,238 | 264,202 | 104 | עירובין |
| 638.92 | 2,507.10 | 24,918 | 97,777 | 39 | ביצה |
| 635.14 | 2,494.26 | 89,555 | 351,691 | 141 | חולין |
| 587.31 | 2,323.16 | 32,302 | 127,774 | 55 | סוכה |
| 582.73 | 2,299.84 | 69,345 | 273,681 | 119 | זבחים |
| 512.22 | 2,049.89 | 4,610 | 18,449 | 9 | תמיד |
| 508.82 | 1,978.57 | 89,044 | 346,249 | 175 | בבא בתרא |
| 430.52 | 1,670.32 | 27,984 | 108,571 | 65 | נזיר |
| 384.00 | 1,535.95 | 8,064 | 32,255 | 21 | מעילה |
| 383.06 | 1,499.28 | 34,475 | 134,935 | 90 | נדרים |

Comment: Where did you find that?

Comment: Downloaded the texts from mechon mamre, and wrote a computer program to count everything.

Comment: @Shalom Can you add Shekalim (as printed in the Bavli) to the list?

Comment: If you still have the code, could you post it somewhere (like a [gist](https://gist.github.com/)) for other people to see?

Comment: Can someone explain what the columns "letters/daf" and "words/daf" signify in the chart linked by @user1887 , please?

Comment: @Oliver a daf is a (2-sided) page of Gemara, as defined by the pages that have become standard the past century plus. Each page has some text of the Talmud, surrounded by commentary. If the material is fairly simple, expect many letters/words of Talmudic text per page (not a lot of space needed for commentary). If the material is complex (or the commentaries verbose), each page will have fewer letters of Talmudic text, and much more commentary instead. I compared letters vs. words to see if there was much difference (do certain tractates use longer words on average?).

Comment: @Oliver that's precisely the point of this question: people know that number of daf is a poor measure of Gemara text length, because text-per-def varies tremendously. Open a Gemara Brachos and you'll see tons of text, very little commentary -- leading some to the mistaken belief that it has the longest text. What they are accurately noticing is it has the highest words-per-daf rate. (A better quick measure of text length is simply: how many chapters are there?)

Comment: Cited in Footnote 4 in [this](https://seforimblog.com/2020/02/new-notes-added-in-the-koren-talmud-bavli/) Seforim Blog post

Comment: @Shalom just wondering, how did you convert the Mechon Mamre htm files to txt files? I am attempting a similar project to what you are doing, and I need a txt copy of the Talmud...

Comment: @fartgeek https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694482/converting-html-to-text-with-python . I think I'd actually done it with just raw string manipulation ... but welcome to the 2020s -- use BeautifulSoup. Just remember that those files are in cp1255 and not the default utf-8. text=open('myfile.html', encoding='cp1255')

Comment: @Shalom thank you

Answer (score 7):

No, Shabbos is the longest.

See the comments here: [Shelosha Veshishim - mi yodeya?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2184/shelosha-veshishim-mi-yodeya/2208#2208)

Comment: So at least I'm not the only one who heard the debunked Brachos rumor ... I wonder where it came from.

Comment: @Shalom They say it in the name of the Vilna Gaon, but I have no idea why.

Comment: @Shalom 1/2 While I’ve heard the rumor too for many years, with different names of masechtot and in the name of various people I’ve never seen a legitimate source from the VG. But supposing the rumor is true I wonder if a) the individual(s) who asserted so was simply wrong or b) the the computation of words yielded different totals; IOW, Rabbi X counted קמ״ל as three words (=קא משמע לן) whereas the computer counts it as one. Same goes for *dozens* of other acronyms.

Comment: @Yehoshua 2/2 Furthermore, supposing the VG did assert so, I wonder (but doubt) if his emendations and the textual variants between the edition(s) he used (Amsterdam 1644 & Frankfurt on the Oder 1715) and the Mamre text (IIRC they use the Vilna ed.) could make up for the discrepancy.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to share a useful file I created based on [Shalom](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/21/shalom)'s wonderfully detailed answer to the question. Many thanks to him!
I created a card that lists the masechtot in order of Seder and then in order of length. So it gives some sense of the order of Shas but puts the largest Masechta first, etc.

This card portrays the relative length in units of 0.5% of the words of Shas, approximately, and can be used to mark off progress in learning, chazara and mastering the knowledge, with the level being self-reported. Comments and suggestions welcome.
[image] Here is a PDF [Length of Masechtot in Words - Track Learning and Chazaros](https://acrobat.adobe.com/id/urn:aaid:sc:US:42c0f0cd-3850-49d6-9c37-2a988e77157f)