# List of easiest mesachtos according to Chazal

Tags: talmud-gemara

Is there a source anywhere that show us in any way what Chazal thought were the easiest to hardest Talmud Bavli tractates?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18886/15256

Comment: הרוצה שיחכים יעסוק בדיני ממונות.

Comment: Looking over Horayos 13b again, I’m not sure they viewed Uktzin as difficult, or just difficult to Rabban Gamliel

Comment: Lol. Even if it was difficult for Rabbi Gamliel, I can assure you, that it'll be very hard for me! @DonielF

Comment: Not Chazal, but Tiferes Yisrael on the last Mishnah in Kinnim writes that it was such a difficult Masechta for him to work on it took ten years off his life.