# Talmud Statistics

Tags: talmud-gemara, number, talmud-bavli, aleph-bet-letters, statistics

How many letters are in the Talmud?*

How many words are in the Talmud?

How many dafim are in the Talmud?

How many tractates are in the Talmud?

How many letters, words, and dafim are in every tractate of Talmud?

- When I say Talmud I mean the classic Vilna edition of Talmud Bavli. (The one with Shekalim)

I just want to get a sense of how big it is. And to compare with other texts. Statistics.

Comment: אייתו אשלי ומשחו

Comment: If you're going to need all this info, you may want to just buy a copy of the Bar-Ilan responsa CD - it has word and character counts for everything it includes. Note that their online version does not include word counts, so you'll actually need to buy the CD or USB version.

Comment: Reminds me of the Mila-Yomi program... http://nachmang.wordpress.com/2011/09/20/%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%92%D7%95%D7%9F-%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%94-%D7%94%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%AA/

Comment: As per the OP's own words [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/44265/9682) I vote to close as a duplicate of https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2672/. Any complete answer to that question will have to justify it by answering this question in the process.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is the longest masechta?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2672/what-is-the-longest-masechta)

Answer (score 2):

I can answer only 1 of your questions, as I have memorized the names of all the 63 tractates ... unless you want to include the "small tractates" that appear after Avodah zarah (such as Avot D'Rav Nattan) - I think that would add another 5 or 6 to that number.

Many tractates only have mishnah - not Gemarrah.

[Wikipedia article on Talmud](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talmud) should provide you with sufficient statistics to answer most of your other questions such as number of chapters in each tractate, and perhaps, number of pages, as well.

If you want to know how many pages are in each tractate as well as the entire Bavli, try any Daf Yomi site. The one I use to study daily is [Dafnotes](http://dafnotes.com).

Word and letter stats may be a bit trickier. I don't know anyone who has calculated this.

Comment: any way you do it is fine. But just say what number you are counting on e.g X Tractates excluding small tractates and tractates that do not have mishna.

Comment: Go by 1st answer, then, which is 63.

Answer (score 1):

I was searching through this site and I saw this question [what is the longest masechta?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2672/what-is-the-longest-masechta)

So this link answers all my questions

http://www.tallitstore.com/v/vspfiles/util/word_counts_mesechta.htm

Comment: 2nd link is 404