# What are some relatively easy gemaras to learn?

Tags: talmud-gemara, torah-study

Please list masechtas that easier to learn.

Don't mention Megillah I already learned that one

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya zunior! Note questions here should not be [opinion based](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Rather they should provide benchmarks to define an objectively correct answer. For example consider describing which characteristics of massekhet Megillah you liked. For example: It is relatively short, it rarely has single discussions that stretch for more than a couple of pages, few of its _sugyot_ are intertwined, it contains a lengthy aggadic section. | Consider clarifying which of these characteristics, or other characteristics you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Let's restate the question:

> I just finished Megillah, and am now looking for a complete mesechta that's comparably easy-to-learn-and-finish.

So let's consult [this table](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/2677/21):

Two easy measures of a mesechta are its apparent length, as measured by daf; and "density" -- how little commentary does each page have. (The less commentary, *presumably*, the easier the material as it needs less explanation.) Additionally, tractates in the same Seder *tend* to cover related material.

Megillah ranks #9 on shortness-by-daf, and #4 on ease-as-measured-by-density, and it's in Seder Moed. By that logic, **Taanis is probably your best bet**: it's also in Seder Moed, #8 on shortness-by-daf, and #6 on ease-by-density.

(Let's look at the top five ease-by-density: Brachos is double the length; Krisos assumes a whole lot of background knowledge so that our poor protagonist can violate fifteen impossible things before breakfast; Horiyos is kind of abstract; you did Megillah; and Sanhedrin's super-long. Then comes Taanis!)

Answer (score 1):

The very first one. You Berachot, the first page. It has been tought and explained extensively and you can find many resources related to it. Search Daf Yomi and you'll find it.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Elazar! Consider clarifying what about Massekhet Berakhot makes it particularly easy to learn.

Comment: @mevaqesh he already explained. It has been taught extensively and their are many resources for it, that help explain it in a easy to understand package.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should learn Brachos and Perek Eilu Metzios from Bava Metzia. They are relatively easy to learn and there are tons of resources online to help people studying them.