# Longest to Shortest tractates of Bavli by daf

Tags: talmud-gemara, statistics

Guessing it's been asked & answered already but not seeing it clearly.
I simply would like a listing of longest to shortest (or vice versa!) tractates in Bavli by daf, ideally listing the number of daf/tractate. Thanks so much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is the longest masechta?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2672/what-is-the-longest-masechta)

Comment: @DonielF This one also asks the shortest one! 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the list of the longest to shortest Masechtot in the Talmud Bavli (H/T to [this helpful answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/2677/18474))  based off the amount of daf per Masechta:

- **Bava Basra** - 176
- **Shabbos** - 157
- **Chullin** - 142
- **Yevamos** - 122
- **Pesachim** - 121
- **Zevachim** - 120
- **Bava Kamma** - 119
- **Bava Metzia** - 119
- **Sanhedrin** - 113
- **Ketubot** - 112
- **Menachos** - 110
- **Eruvin** - 105
- **Nedarim** - 91
- **Gittin** - 90
- **Yoma** - 88
- **Kiddushin** - 82
- **Avodah Zarah** - 76
- **Niddah** - 73
- **Nazir** - 66
- **Berachos** - 64
- **Bechoros** - 61
- **Sukkah** - 56
- **Sotah** - 49
- **Shevuos** - 49
- **Beitzah** - 40
- **Rosh Hashanah** - 35
- **Temurah** - 34
- **Arachin** - 34
- **Megillah** - 32
- **Ta'anis** - 31
- **Mo'ed Kattan** - 29
- **Kerisus** - 28
- **Chagigah** - 27
- **Makkos** - 24
- **Me'ilah** - 22
- **Horayos** - 14
- **Tamid** - 10