# Longest to Shortest tractates of Yerushalmi by daf

Tags: talmud-gemara, talmud-yerushalmi, statistics

A follow on from [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/103297/longest-to-shortest-tractates-of-bavli-by-daf): I simply would like a listing of longest to shortest (or vice versa!) tractates in Yerushalmi by daf, ideally listing the number of daf/tractate.

Comment: What printing? Why would you want to document this arbitrary metric?

Comment: @DoubleAA To see which masechtos in Yerushalmi are short and which are long, besides curiosity

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Use word count if you want to find that out.

Comment: @DoubleAA it's not complete nonsense.  number of pages ~ (number of words) + (font size ratio) * (number of words in nosei keilim), which could be a metric for length weighted by complexity.

Comment: @Heshy whatever makes him happy

Comment: @JoshuaPearl This post would be more compelling if you'd [edit] in some details about why you're interested in this information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the list of the longest to shortest Masechtot in the Talmud Yerushalmi   based off the amount of daf per Masechta. (Source: [Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org/texts/Talmud/Yerushalmi), which uses the text of [Mechon Mamre](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/b/r/r0.htm), which is based on the Pietrkov edition.)

- **Shabbos** - 92 (1a-92b)
- **Yevamos** - 85 (1a-85a)
- **Ketubot** - 72 (1a-72a)
- **Pesachim** - 71 (1a-71b)
- **Berachos** - 68 (1a-68a)
- **Eruvin** - 65 (1a-65b)
- **Terumot** - 59 (1a-59a)
- **Sanhedrin** - 57 (1a-57b)
- **Gittin** - 54 (1a-54b)
- **Kiddushin** - 48 (1a-48b)
- **Nazir** - 47 (1a-47b)
- **Sotah** - 47 (1a-47a)
- **Bava Kamma** - 44 (1a-44b)
- **Shevuot** - 44 (1a-44b)
- **Kilayim** -  44 (1a-44b)
- **Yoma** - 42 (1a-42b)
- **Nedarim** - 40 (1a-40a)
- **Avodah Zarah** - 37 (1a-37b)
- **Peah** - 37 (1a-37b)
- **Bava Metzia** - 37 (1a-37a)
- **Bava Basra** - 34 (1a-34a)
- **Demai** - 34 (1a-34a)
- **Megillah** - 34 (1a-34a)
- **Shekalim** - 33 (1a-33b)
- **Ma'aser Sheini** 33 - (1a-33b)
- **Shevi'it** - 31 (1a-31a)
- **Challah** - 28 (1a-28b)
- **Sukkah** - 26 (1a-26b)
- **Ta'anis** - 26 (1a-26b)
- **Ma'asrot** - 26 (1a-26b)
- **Beitzah** - 22 (1a-22b)
- **Chagigah** - 22 (1a-22b)
- **Rosh Hashanah** - 22 (1a-22a)
- **Orlah** - 20 (1a-20b)
- **Moed Kattan** - 19 (1a-19b)
- **Horayos** - 19 (1a-19b)
- **Niddah** - 13 (1a-13a)
- **Bikkurim** - 13 (1a-13a)
- **Makkos** - 9 (1a-9b)