# Which Perek in mishnayos has the fewest words?

Tags: words, mishna

I'm looking for perokim of mishnayos that have the **fewest words**.

(I've been able to find, via this helpful forum!, which perokim have the **fewest mishnayos**, but I'm looking for the perokim with the **fewest words**.)

Comment: Why are you interested in this fact?

Comment: My guess would be Shabbat 4

Comment: [This](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2672/what-is-the-longest-masechta?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment2797_2677) should work here as well.

Answer (score 6):

I used [R' Dan Be'eri's Mishna](https://archive.org/details/MishnaCorrectedKaufman00WHOLE) which is based on ms kaufman, with some changes. I removed the mishna titles/numbering, his notes that appear in angle brackets, biblical sources in parenthesis, as well as the braisa at the end of פסחים פרק ה and אבות ה:כא which are later additions tacked on to the mishna (marked as such by R' Be'eri). I didn't remove the lines added in parenthesis and brackets, so while I strove to use a reliable version, this is not scientific and should not considered to be using a manuscript edition proper.
These are the shortest chapters by my finds:

שבת ד   107
שבת כא  115
כלים כא 115
כלים כג 116
ערכין א 123

This is the python code to do the count:

```
import re
f = open("mishna text utf.txt","r")
raw= f.read()
tracts= re.split(r'מסכת ',plain)[1:]
lens= []
txts= []
for tract in tracts:
  cur= tract.split()[0]
  count=0
  for chap in re.split(r"^פרק [א-ת][א-ת]?\b",tract, flags=re.MULTILINE)[1:]:
    txts.append(chap)
    count+=1
    lens.append((cur+" "+str(count),len(chap.split() )))
txts= dict(zip([x[0] for x in lens], txts))
lens.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
print(lens)
```

[This](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gytELMgxrvwkz1L5K6XNVaFJTZRiIhm4/view?usp=sharing) is the text file, and [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1obBFjEmWxlrGvAfFTCvTnI52Q9A3-u2T/view) is the word doc prior being converted to .txt which maintains the color coding indicating what R Be'eri added to ms Kaufman.

Note: I got the parsing wrong and realized right after I posted this answer the first time. I think this version checks out. I included a dictionary to check the parsed texts if anyone would like to check the count of any chapter.