# Where can I download a complete text file of the Talmud Bavli?

Tags: talmud-gemara, internet

I am writing a tool in python to analyze the Talmud (e.g. word counts, how many times a specific phrase is used etc.) and I need a free downloadable text file of the Gemara, preferably with Rashi and Tosafos.

Thanks for all your help!!

Comment: Have you looked at Sefaria?

Comment: Mi Yodeya user [Shalom](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/21/shalom) says [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/2677/7539) that he downloaded the text from [Mechon Mamre](https://mechon-mamre.org/b/l/l0.htm) (there's a  הורדת כל הבבלי link on that page). Rashi and Tosfos you'd need to get somewhere else though - I don't see it there.

Comment: @Rish if you put it into an answer I might accept it, depending on whether anyone can find a rashi or tosfos one...

Comment: @magicker72 Where can I download a text file on sefaria??

Comment: @fartgeek https://github.com/Sefaria/Sefaria-Export

Comment: @magicker72 I can't find a 'download' button lol... I know nothing about github. Please tell me how I can download it

Comment: @fartgeek Easiest way is to download *everything* and then pick and choose what to keep. On the main github page, click on the green Code button, and Download ZIP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org/) has all these texts available for free. The easiest way to download them is to go to the Sefaria-Export github repository [here](https://github.com/Sefaria/Sefaria-Export). You can download the entire repository as a ZIP by clicking on the green Code button at the top-right, and then choosing "Download ZIP". The files you're looking for will be in the `txt` folder, then the `Talmud` folder, then the `Bavli` folder. If you just want to download the Bavli folder, you might try one of the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18194523/3307460).

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: I have been having trouble with one issue: If a Tosafos starts one one amud, and ends on another, it cuts off at the end of the amud? Do you have a solution?

Comment: @fartgeek A new tosafot starts with a דיבור המתחיל — some words from the gemara followed by a dash or hyphen. You should be able to find all locations that don't start with a few words + hyphen/dash with a regex search.