# Shiv'a Vachamishim Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows two hundred fifty-seven?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Vote up all interesting and relevant answers.*
- *Accept what I consider the "best" answer.*
- *Move on to the next number.*

*Good luck figuring something out for this one.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

257 years passed between two major massacres of the leading Jewish communities of their respective eras: Spain in 1391, Poland in 1648.

Answer (score 2):

257 years from the birth of Avraham until Yaakov left Lavan (I'd appreciate if anyone can add why this is more than arbitrary):

100 till Yitzchak + 60 until Yaakov + [63](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2184/shelosha-veshishim-mi-yodeya) until the brachos + 14 in yeshivas shem vaever + 20 by Lavan

Answer (score 1):

There were likely 257 years from the death of [Antiochus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiochus_IV_Epiphanes) (−164) until the publication of [Josephus's *Antiquities*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiquities_of_the_Jews) (likely 94).

Comment: How likely?????

Comment: @GershonGold: Well, all the sources I see online that give the date for the _Antiquities_ give 93 or 94. I have no expertise on which to base a choice between those. Thus, as a rough estimate: 50% likely.