# Arba'a Veshishim - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows sixty-four?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point in the next few days, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Comment: Prev: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2165/17423

Comment: Next: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2270/chamisha-veshishim-mi-yodeya?r=SearchResults

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If 64 units comprise the psychological volume of a Torah scholar, one of those -- no more no less -- should be pride.

(This is technically 1:63 ["one *to* sixty-three"], which is the same as 1/64 ["one *in* sixty-four"].  But 63 was already well-covered.  By the way, Bitul b'shishim requires sixty *to* one.)

Talmud Bavli, Sotah 5a:

> א"ר חייא בר אשי אמר רב **ת"ח צריך שיהא בו אחד משמונה בשמינית** א"ר הונא בריה דרב יהושע ומעטרא ליה כי
>    סאסא לשבולתא אמר רבא *בשמתא דאית ביה ובשמתא דלית ביה* א"ר נחמן בר יצחק ל*א מינה ולא מקצתה*

In the course of a lengthy discussion on the evils of "gayva"/pride/arrogance/hubris, we get the statement that in fact a Torah scholar should have just a drop of it ("but it's batel b'shishim"); Rashi explains that a leader can't let people walk all over him, and has to assert his authority *on occasion*.

The next two views in the Talmud are: "darned if you do, darned if you don't" when it comes to having arrogance; and "it's too dangerous, just aim for zero."

The many ways of interpreting these statements -- and which ones we value more than others -- help explain the wide variety of personal leadership styles among Torah scholars.

Answer (score 5):

64 are the verses in the Torah portion of Kedoshim.

This portion also contains 51 mitzvos (according to the reckoning of the Chinuch, and of [R' Moshe Chagiz](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37079&pgnum=121)). So Kedoshim has, as far as I know, the highest verses-to-mitzvos ratio of any parshah.

Answer (score 3):

1) The Mizbeyach and its ramp measured 32 amos apiece, for a total of 64 amos. The combined length was only 62 amos, however, due to the overlap on the ledges of the Yesod and Soveiv. (Zevachim 62b - cool mnemonic there!)

2) It is said in the name of the Gra that if one wanted to fulfill all of the various opinions with regard to the placement of the parshiyos in tefillin (Rashi, Rabbeinu Tam, plus others), he would need to wear 64 pairs in order to satisfy the various permutations. (For everything you ever wanted to know about this topic - see [this chapter](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=19929&st=&pgnum=45&hilite=) by Rav Moshe Shternbuch.)

3) There are 64 *kortov* in a *log*.

Comment: "Kortov in a log."  Or very roughly, half-tablespoons in a pint.

Comment: #1 is great but belongs with 62, IMHO.

Comment: "half-tablespoons in a pint" - anything Jewishly significant about that?

Comment: No, sorry.  Just trying to give people a rough idea of what these units of measurement are.  On the scale of tablespoons, not swimming pools.

Comment: If a log is roughly a pint (putting the reviis at 4 fluid ounces), then the kortov is half a tablespoon.

Comment: I guess it could be relevant, if someone has ketores and wants to know how much fruit-honey he can add before it reaches the level of "ein adam yachol laamod bah mipnei reychah."

Comment: Was kortov davka?  Did they have a smaller unit of volume between a kortov and a "kolshehu"?  And for those aiming for approximate measures, this would mean a ~teaspoon of fruit-honey into a ~365 lbs batch of incense.

Comment: Dave, you should post your answers separately so that each can be commented/voted on.

Comment: YDK: Makes sense, but last time I tried that, the system urged me to combine the second answer with the first. I suppose you're saying that's not really the policy here...

Comment: Dave and YDK, The technology this site runs on has that warning when you try to answer twice to the same question. It's a warning, not a rule. In many cases, it's more appropriate to put all of your information in one answer. In the case of this game, I go along with YDK in preferring one fact per answer, but it doesn't matter much.

Answer (score 1):

(**לכל "חיה" יש ששים וארבע כנפיים**  (רבינו בחיי במדבר ט"ו ל"ח

The Angels which are called "Chayos" have 64 wings each. (Rabeinu Bachye Bamidbar 15:38)

Answer (score 0):

64 years from *Avraham*'s death to *Ever*'s. (Yes, *Avraham* died first.)