# Chamisha Veshishim - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows sixty-five?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point in the next few days, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/106297/759

Comment: Prev: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2234/arbaa-veshishim-mi-yodeya?r=SearchResults

Comment: Next: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2296/shisha-veshishim-mi-yodeya?r=SearchResults

Answer (score 4, accepted):

65 years passed from when Amos prophesied the eventual exile of the Ten Tribes, until that exile actually occurred and the the kingdom of Israel ("Ephraim") ceased to exist. (Isaiah 7:8 and commentaries there)

Answer (score 4):

Mahalalel was 65 when Yared was born to him (Bereishis 5:15); Chanoch was 65 when Mesushelach was born to him (ibid. v. 21).

Answer (score 4):

65 is the median number of years ("once every sixty or seventy years...") that it took for the leftover ketores to accumulate and add up to 184 *maneh*, which is half of the yearly ketores recipe. (Kerisos 6b)

Comment: I've always wondered how often in Jewish history this actually happened -- 65 years of calm, prosperous, normal Temple operation.

Comment: It unfortunately happened quite often that the Beis Hamikdash was despoiled, either by Jewish kings or by non-Jewish invaders; but would they have necessarily done anything to the saved-up ketores? They tended to usually be after silver and gold, not spice mixtures.

Comment: How often can a shul keep track of stuff sitting in its office for a few weeks?  Months?  Years?  Decades?

Comment: I expect that the Beit Hamikdash, with its regimented duties, controlled access, and shifts of personnel who had to take over from each other periodically, was likely better organized than the average shul office. But then, maybe I'm looking back with ketoret-smoked glasses.

Answer (score 3):

65 is the gematria of הלל, Hallel *(or Hillel)*. The significance of this is expounded in [Sefer Hap'liah](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8_%D7%94%D7%A4%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%90%D7%94_-_%D7%93%22%D7%94_%D7%90%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%99_%D7%9B%D7%90%D7%9F_%D7%9B%D7%9C_%D7%94%D7%90%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%AA%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%AA%D7%9F) as follows:

> הסר כעס מלבך ר"ת עולים הלל, במספר הכ"ם
>   ס"ה והלל עולה ג"כ ס"ה

Comment: Is he saying Hallel (when we're focused on praising God, we don't get angry) or Hillel (the sage on whom people took bets if they could get him to lose his temper)?    Though the mekubalim believe the proper spelling of Hillel is with a yud.

Comment: You're right, he probably means Hillel! I was wondering what Hallel had to do with minimizing anger.