# Shelosha Veshiv'im - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows seventy-three?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point in the next few days, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Comment: Prev: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2426/shnayim-veshivim-mi-yodeya?r=SearchResults

Comment: Next: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2478/arbaa-veshivim-mi-yodeya?r=SearchResults

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *[molad](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/216238/jewish/Molad-Times.htm#notes)* (average synodic lunar period) is expressed by Rabban Gamliel (in Rosh Hashanah 25a) as 29 1/2 days, 2/3 of an hour, and **73** chalakim (1 chelek = 3 1/3 seconds).

Answer (score 3):

73 may have been the Sanhedrin of Shamaya and Avtalyon.

Both were converts to Judaism; there's some discussion whether they were full voting members of the Sanhedrin, or only served in an advisory, non-voting capacity (in which case 71 +2 = 73).

---

73 are the volumes of Schottenstein.

(It fits the beat!)

Answer (score 2):

73 is the regular (alef = 1 ... tav = 400) [gematria](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gematria#Methods) of "חכמה" (wisdom) and the reverse (in decimal representation) of the ordinal-value (alef = 1 ... tav = 22) gematria of the same word ([37](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1528/shiva-ushloshim-mi-yodeya/1535#1535)).

Answer (score 2):

73 are the verses in [Yoel](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t14.htm).​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Modern Israel is also 73 years old as of now. Sefer Yoel talks about the restoration of Zion and the time of Moshiach.

Comment: https://www.jns.org/opinion/73-bible-verses-in-honor-of-israels-73rd-birthday/

Answer (score 1):

73 is the number of answers to [shiv'im mi yodeya](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2365/shivim-mi-yodeya)!

Answer (score 1):

73 are the number of "gates of wisdom" presented in Sefer haChochma by R. Eleazar ben Yehudah of Worms (160—1238). The number of these "gates" is determined by the numerical value of the Hebrew word for Chochma.