# Arba'a Veshiv'im - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows seventy-four?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point in the next few days, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Comment: Prev: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2450/shelosha-veshivim-mi-yodeya?r=SearchResults

Comment: Next: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2495/chamisha-veshivim-mi-yodeya?r=SearchResults

Answer (score 4, accepted):

74 are the mitzvos in Parshas Ki Teitzei, highest number in any single Torah portion.

Answer (score 3):

74 is the age of Yishmael when Yaakov was born. (Megillah 17a)

Answer (score 3):

74 are the thousands of Yehudah.  ([Numbers 1:27](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0401.htm)).

It fits the beat!

This was the highest population of any tribe.

Answer (score 2):

74 are the Chapters of [Zera'im](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeraim) (which are definitely Mishna).

Answer (score 2):

For 74 years, the first of our "fathers" was known as Avram. At age 99, his name was changed to Avraham ([Breishit 17:1 - 5](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9597&st=&pgnum=208).)

He lived 175 years.

Answer (score 2):

[Nazir 60b](https://www.sefaria.org/Nazir.60b.3?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&lang=bi) speaks about a Nazir who was a confirmed leper:

> מוּחְלָט סָפֵק וְטָמֵא וַדַּאי אוֹכֵל בְּקָדָשִׁים לְאַחַר שְׁלֹשִׁים וְשִׁבְעָה יָמִים וְשׁוֹתֶה יַיִן וּמִיטַּמֵּא לְמֵתִים **לְאַחַר שִׁבְעִים וְאַרְבָּעָה יָמִים**
>
> (A nazirite whose status as) a confirmed leper was uncertain and who was definitely impure (from a dead body) partakes of sacrificial food after thirty-seven days and he may drink wine and become impure from the dead **only after seventy-four days**.

Answer (score 1):

[Ezra 2:40](https://www.sefaria.org/Ezra.2.40?ven=The_Holy_Scriptures:_A_New_Translation_(JPS_1917)&lang=bi):

> הַלְוִיִּ֑ם בְּנֵי־יֵשׁ֧וּעַ וְקַדְמִיאֵ֛ל לִבְנֵ֥י הוֹדַוְיָ֖ה **שִׁבְעִ֥ים וְאַרְבָּעָֽה**׃ (ס)
>
> The Levites: the children of Jeshua and Kadmiel, of the children of Hodaviah, **seventy and four**.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Rav Asher Weiss](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b-9VJGzaULA), 74 is the gematria of Hashem's name when it transitions from din to rachamim.

Comment: Ari HaKodesh, Shaarei hakavanos, drush yud beis I believe he said.