# Chamisha Veshiv'im - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows seventy-five?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point in the next few days, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Comment: Prev: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2478/arbaa-veshivim-mi-yodeya?r=SearchResults

Comment: Next: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2520/shisha-veshivim-mi-yodeya?r=SearchResults

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your count, seventy-five are the tractates of the Mishna (63) plus the [minor tractates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_tractates):

1. Avos D'Rabi Nasan (counting as separate from Avos)
2. Sofrim
3. Semachos
4. Kallah, Kallah Rabsi (counting as one)
5. Derech Eretz Rabba and Zuta, the latter including Perek HaShalom
6. Sefer Torah
7. Mezuzah
8. Tefillin
9. Tzitzis
10. Avadaim
11. Geirim
12. Kusim

---

Seventy-five was Avraham's age (then "Avram") [when he left for Israel](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0112.htm).  Though this was not the first move in his life; it appears his father had initiated a move and hadn't completed it.

---

להם ("to them") has Gematria 75, and it appears more often in Tanach than all other 75-words combined.

Every book of Tanach (counting the Twelve individually) contains at least one 75-word, except for Nachum.

Comment: Checkmark for the one that gives hope to those who want to make Aliya but can't for the next few years, at least.

Answer (score 2):

75 are the years that Avraham and Yitzchak lived as contemporaries (since Sarah bore Yitzchak when Avraham was 100 years old, and he lived to 175).

Comment: Sadly, we don't see much interaction between them after the Akeida  Some say that becoming an Olah Temimah had a cost.

Comment: I don't know that this proves much. The Written Torah tells us next to nothing about Avraham's first 75 years either, even though we know from the Gemara and Midrashim how much he accomplished during that time. The Torah is after all pretty sparing with details.