# Shisha Veshiv'im - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows seventy-six?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point in the next few days, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Comment: Prev: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2495/chamisha-veshivim-mi-yodeya?r=SearchResults

Comment: Next: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2549/shiva-veshivim-mi-yodeya?r=SearchResults

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sarai was 76 when Hagar gave birth to Yishmael.  (10 yrs behind Avram)

Answer (score 4):

Seventy-six is the length of the [Slaughterhouse](http://www.yucs.org/~rweiser/mikdash/mitbach.html). (See Mishneh Torah: [Hilchot Beit Habechira 5](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1007198/jewish/Chapter-5.htm):15-16 and 5:12.)

Comment: Good find! I always pictured the boards that the hooks were attached to for hanging and skinning as being vertical. I guess you learn something new every number.

Comment: Well, who knows if this artist's rendering is authoritative on that point.

Comment: I hope this isn't all we learn from this number. I haven't yet had to accept my own answer in this series, and I don't want to start now.