# Tish'a Veshiv'im - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows seventy-nine?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point in the next few days, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Comment: Prev: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2572/shemona-veshivim-mi-yodeya?r=SearchResults

Comment: Next: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2602/shemonim-mi-yodeya?r=SearchResults

Answer (score 3, accepted):

79 is the oldest age at which it is possible to die as a result of Kares.

Comment: Whose opinion is this? I seem to remember a מחלוקת in תוספות somewhere proposing 50 and 60 as possible cut-offs based on references to the ages of לויים in the תורה. . .

Comment: The Gemara in Moed Katan 28a describes two types of kares: כרת דשני, kares of years, which is the "standard" premature death between ages 50-60. The other type is כרת דיומי, kares of days, which means a sudden death. This second type is only until one reaches the age of Gevuros, i.e., 80 years old.