# Shnayim Ushmonim - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows eighty-two?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point in the next few days, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Comment: Prev: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2638/echad-ushmonim-mi-yodeya

Comment: Next: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2660/shelosha-ushmonim-mi-yodeya

Answer (score 4, accepted):

82 is the age to which two successive Gerrer Rebbes lived: R' Avraham Mordechai (the Imrei Emes), and his son R' Yisroel (the Beis Yisroel).

Answer (score 4):

The Mishnah in Shekalim Ch. 8, according to one version of the text, states that the Paroches (curtain) in the Temple was made by 82 young girls (ריבות). The standard text reads 82 myriads (רבוא), which equals 820,000, referring either to the number of gold coins it cost [Rambam, and Taklin Chadatin in the name of the Gaon], or to the number of strands it contained [Rashi Chullin 90b].

Comment: Any guess what about its construction that would need 80-something people?

Comment: Well, it was 20 x 40 amos, and a person takes up a amah, so 80 people would be needed if they were lined up along the two lengthwise sides. Maybe the two others were for logistic support...