# Shelosha Ushmonim - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows eighty-three?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point in the next few days, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35401

Comment: Prev: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2652/shnayim-ushmonim-mi-yodeya

Comment: Next: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2687/arbaa-ushmonim-mi-yodeya

Answer (score 5, accepted):

83 sections of halachos in the Rambam's Yad.

Comment: Interestingly, too, he lived 70 years minus exactly 83 days (his grandson, R' David, notes this).

Comment: Truly interesting, but what is the significance of that? And wouldn't it have been better if he had lived for 70 years **plus** 83 days?

Comment: See footnote 83 (!) at http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15971&st=&pgnum=263, where the Lubavitcher Rebbe zt"l observes that this is exactly the point: the missing 83 days are made up by the 83 sections of the Yad, thus bringing the Rambam's life to exactly 70 years.

Comment: Something tells me the Rambam would not have seen it that way.

Comment: So we'll ask him when Moshiach comes...

Comment: According to the Rambam, he'll still be dead!

Answer (score 6):

The Scriptural term מחלה (illness), which the Gemara defines as pathology of the gall bladder or bile, has 83 sicknesses associated with it, equivalent to the gematria of the word מחלה. (Bava Kama 92b and elsewhere)

Answer (score 6):

83 was Aharon's age when he and Moshe first confronted Pharaoh (Ex. 7:7).

Comment: I'd heard it suggested that Moshe and Aharon each reached identical spiritual levels; however, Aharon was 3 years older and thus had 3 more years to do it.  So Moshe's spiritual growth rate was higher.

Answer (score 0):

- In the year 2447, Moses was 80 the year that the Israelites left Egypt and Aaron was **83** (as noted here: [Did Levi see Moshe and Aaron?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/34137/did-levi-see-moshe-and-aaron)); See also: [Why does the posuk tell us how old Moshe was when he spoke to Pharoh?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29686/why-does-the-posuk-tell-us-how-old-moshe-was-when-he-spoke-to-pharoh/29735#29735); See [How old was Moshe at the splitting of the sea?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/70635/how-old-was-moshe-at-the-splitting-of-the-sea/70639#70639); See here for slight contradiction based on Seder HaDorot: [Moshe's age and the timeline of the exodus](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8438/moshes-age-and-the-timeline-of-the-exodus/8466#8466)
- Asaph ben Berechiah (11th-10th cent BCE) Israelite musician. He was one of the Levites appointed by David to supervise music in the Sanctuary. Psalms 50 and 73-**83** are attributed to him. The sons of Asaph were singers in the Temple during the reign of the kings of Judah (10th-6th cent, BCE) and at the time of Ezra and Nehemiah. See: [What is known about Asaph son of Berechiah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/104281/what-is-known-about-asaph-son-of-berechiah/104289#104289)
- **83** is 13 years into your 'second' lifetime (See Tehillim 90:10) attributing to some men having a 2nd bar mitzvah. See: [Where does the custom of a second "bar mitzvah" at 83 come from?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35401/where-does-the-custom-of-a-second-bar-mitzvah-at-83-come-from/35402#35402)
- Our forefather Ya'akov did not marry until he was **83** years old (Megillah 17a).[Why did Yaakov wait to marry?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/48531/why-did-yaakov-wait-to-marry/54006#54006)
- Originally, Psalm 83 followed the Chazzan's Kaddish (Kadish Titkabel) See [Why are Ashre and Alenu considered communal prayers?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22674/why-are-ashre-and-alenu-considered-communal-prayers/56307#56307)
- History of Aleinu: Shir Mizmor La'asaf Psalm 83 was institued after the Ga'Onic period See: [Why no Kaddish yatom after alainu in siddur tefillo sfas yisrael, Shabbas Mincha?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/61547/why-no-kaddish-yatom-after-alainu-in-siddur-tefillo-sfas-yisrael-shabbas-mincha/61555#61555)