# Chamisha Ushmonim - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows eighty-five?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point in the next few days, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Comment: Prev: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2687/arbaa-ushmonim-mi-yodeya

Comment: Next: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2719/shisha-ushmonim-mi-yodeya

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A Sefer Torah parchment that contains at least 85 letters, equaling the number of letters in *Vayehi Binso'a* (the smallest "sefer" in the Torah), is considered a "sefer" with regard to making one's hands tamei. (Mishnah Yadayim 3:5)

Comment: Checkmark because a Halachic limit specifying 85 has much 85-ness.

Answer (score 5):

85 are the verses in Parshas Vayechi, which records Yaakov's blessings to his children and grandchildren. Appropriately enough, the mnemonic at the end of the parshah is פה אל פה - "[speaking] mouth to mouth" (in English terms, "face to face").

Answer (score 4):

Doeg killed 85 Kohanim who were "linen apron" wearers (prominent Kohanim) among the other Kohanim of Nov. (Shmuel A 22:18)

Answer (score 4):

Kalev was 85 years old at the time of the distribution of the land of Eretz Yisrael. (Yehoshua 10:14)

Answer (score 4):

Sanhedrin 97b records Eliyahu HaNavi's statement that the pre-messianic world will span at least 85 Yovel cycles (4,250 years).

Answer (score 1):

Megilas Rus has 85 Pesukim which is also the Gematria of Boaz.