# Shisha Ushmonim - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows eighty-six?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point in the next few days, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Comment: Prev: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2700/chamisha-ushmonim-mi-yodeya

Comment: Next: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2738/shiva-ushmonim-mi-yodeya

Answer (score 6, accepted):

86 is gym-atria for elokim, gd of all powers meaning one who has complete power over all worlds including nature. ---86

Comment: Koachyah, Welcome to mi.yodeya, and thanks very much for participating in the Mi.yodeya Series! I look forward to seeing you around.

Comment: And also, the gematria of הטבע. The Sifrei Machshava deal with the significance of this.

Comment: Another one with the same gematria is the name יוסי. The Mishnah in Sanhedrin (56a) says that when Beis Din examined witnesses to an act of blasphemy, they used the word יוסי as an allusion to Hashem's Name. Rashi explains that this word was used because it has 4 letters like the Shem HaMeforash, and also because it has the same gematria as Elokim.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/23050

Answer (score 7):

Miriam, the sister of Moshe Rabbeinu, was born 86 years before Yetzias Mitzrayim. That was when the Egyptians increased the Israelites' slavery, which is reflected in Miriam's name (from the root Mar, bitterness). (Shir Hashirim Rabbah 2:11)

Answer (score 5):

Avraham was 86 when Yishmael was born.

Answer (score 5):

86 cc = 1 revi'is (the amount of wine for kiddush and the Four Cups, and a significant amount of liquid in many other halachic contexts), according to R' Avraham Chaim Naeh. (He gives a useful mnemonic for this: כוס equals 86.)

Comment: 86.4 technically.