# Shiv'a Ushmonim - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows eighty-seven?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point in the next few days, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Comment: Prev: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2719/shisha-ushmonim-mi-yodeya

Comment: Next: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2758/shemona-ushmonim-mi-yodeya

Answer (score 3, accepted):

87 is the number of words in Baruch She'amar.   It says that G-d is praised "in the mouth" --  בפה -- of his people.  בפה has Gematria 87, for that reason.  But some replace it with בפי, for grammatical correctness (even if it means losing the gematria).

Source: Rabbi Artscroll.

Comment: My impression was that we all said b'fi until artscroll changed it.

Comment: Nope - it goes back at least to the Arizal's siddur.

Answer (score 3):

87 years passed from the establishment of the Jewish kingship (when Shaul was crowned, in the year 2882 since creation) until they came under the domination of a foreign king (Shishak the king of Egypt, who invaded and conquered parts of the Land of Israel in the fifth year of King Rechavam, 2969 since creation - I Kings 14:25ff and II Chron. 12:2ff).

Comment: That's all?  Somewhat depressing, isn't it ...

Comment: Well, they did later regain their independence for various periods of time.

Answer (score 3):

There are 87 pesukim in Parshas Chukas.

Answer (score 1):

87 is the gematria of Paz, a rare and valuable metal used to illustrate the value of Torah: "Hanechmadim mizahav, umipaz rav."