# Shemona Ushmonim - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows eighty-eight?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point in the next few days, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Comment: Prev: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2738/shiva-ushmonim-mi-yodeya

Comment: Next: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2775/tisha-ushmonim-mi-yodeya

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moshe Rabbeinu was 88 days old when his mother placed him (in a basket) in the Nile River - this according to the opinion that this occurred on the 6th of Sivan, later to be the day of the Giving of the Torah.

(Rabbeinu Bechayei to Ex. 2:2)

Answer (score 2):

According to Chizkuni, it was customary for those who lived in Avraham's time to make a feast on the day one's child is weaned.  So Avram probably made one for Yishmael at the age of 88.