# Tish'a Ushmonim - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows eighty-nine?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point in the next few days, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Comment: Prev: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2758/shemona-ushmonim-mi-yodeya

Comment: Next: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2807/tishim-mi-yodeya

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Number of pesukim in the parasha of the korbanos of the nesiim (and the gematria of chanuka)

Answer (score 4):

The Beis Hamikdash, as renovated by Herod, stood for 89 years (he started the work in 19 BCE, and it was destroyed in 70 CE).

Answer (score 3):

Sara's age when visited by malachim