# Echad Vetish'im - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows ninety-one?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point in the next few days, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Comment: Prev: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2807/tishim-mi-yodeya

Comment: Next: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2847/shnayim-vetishim-mi-yodeya

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't normally do gematrias, but this has a double 91ness:

91 is the gematria of sukkah (malei) as well as the perek number in tehillim which expresses trust in Hashem's protection.

Comment: Perhaps also alluded to in the phrase צא** מדירת קבע**.

Comment: Another checkmark for seasonality.

Answer (score 7):

YDK's answer reminded me of another double gematria:

אמן = the names הוי-ה and א-דני, equaling 91.

[Baal Haturim (to Deut. 27:26) comments that this is why "one who answers Amen is greater than the one who recited the blessing" (Berachos 53b), because his Amen encapsulates two Divine names.]

Answer (score 5):

Eruvin 56a cites Shmuel's statement that the interval between the beginning of one season and the next is 91 days (plus 7.5 hours). This is based on dividing a solar year of [nominally] 365.25 days into 4 parts. (Rashi)

Answer (score 5):

91 are the total number of parshiyos (open and closed sections) in Chumash Bereishis - the least of any of the five chumashim, even though it's the longest of them.

Answer (score 1):

*Yaakov* was 91 at *Yosef*'s birth.

Answer (score 0):

There are 91 leap years in a cycle of 247 years.