# Shnayim Vetish'im - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows ninety-two?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point next year, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Comment: Prev: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2830/echad-vetishim-mi-yodeya

Comment: Next: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2890/shelosha-vetishim-mi-yodeya

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R' Chisda lived to be 92 years old (Moed Katan 28a). As did the Lubavitcher Rebbe, zt"l.

At that age, too, Rebbi's maidservant still had sharp enough senses to be able to taste a dish and make sure it was cooked properly. (Shabbos 152a)

Comment: R' Chisda and Rebbi are also zt"l!

Comment: True, but I think there's sort of a "statute of limitations" on how long that honorific is appended. I can't think of any example where it's commonly used for anyone who lived more than a couple of centuries ago.

Answer (score 2):

צב (gematria 92) is used Biblically to mean "covered", usually a covered wagon.

I assume it's based on that that later usage (including modern-day Hebrew) uses it to mean a turtle!

I'm unsure whether the Mishnaic usage is "turtle" or "toad."  Something you'd confuse with a frog, what it sounds like.

Answer (score 2):

92 was the age of the pot-tasting woman who Rav brought as a proof that Barzilai haGiladi was lying when he said he couldn't taste anything because he was old (80).  Shmuel B 19, Gemara Shabbos 152a

Comment: Duplicate of one of Alex's answers. http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/2847/shnayim-vetishim-mi-yodeya/2857#2857