# Shelosha Vetish'im - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows ninety-three?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Comment: Prev: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2847/shnayim-vetishim-mi-yodeya

Comment: next: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2903/arbaa-vetishim-mi-yodeya

Answer (score 5, accepted):

93 gold and silver utensils were used for the daily service in the Beis Hamikdash. (Tamid 3:4)

Answer (score 0):

93 Bais Yaakov girls that gave up their lives rather than be defiled by the Nazis.

(see [here](http://seforim.blogspot.com/2017/07/the-93-beit-yaakov-martyrs-modern.html))