# Arba'a Vetish'im - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows ninety-four?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Comment: prev: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2890/shelosha-vetishim-mi-yodeya

Comment: Next: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2914/chamisha-vetishim-mi-yodeya

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Pharaoh who initiated the oppression of the Jewish People, named Malul, reigned for 94 years. ([Sefer Hayashar](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40009&pgnum=255))

Answer (score 1):

Gematria of לבבכם "your heart"; the obligation in Deuteronomy "to serve G-d with all your heart" is that of prayer (avoda shebelev).  לבבכם is also the most-common 94-word in Tanach.

Answer (score 1):

[Niddah 30a](https://www.sefaria.org/Niddah.30a.1?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&lang=bi)

> מכדי ימי טהרה כמה הוו שתין ושיתא דל שבוע ג' דאטבלינן לה פשו להו שתין נכי חדא שתין נכי חדא ותלתין וה' **תשעין וד'** הויין
>
> The Gemara asks: Now consider, how many days of purity are there, in the case of a woman who gave birth to a female? There are sixty-six days. Therefore, in order to account for all of the nights that might occur immediately after the woman’s period of purity, she must immerse on sixty-six nights, according to Beit Shammai. Remove from this sum the immersions of the third week, when we require the woman to immerse seven times, and sixty less one are left. These sixty-less-one times she immerses after the third week and the thirty-five times she immerses during the first three weeks **are together ninety-four immersions**. (Sefaria translation & notation)

Answer (score 0):

How many years did Levi live in Egypt? Joseph was 39 when he was reunited with his brothers. (He was 30 when he first became viceroy in Egypt (Gen. 41:46), and his family came down after 7 years of plenty and 2 of famine.) According to the Sages, Levi was about 4 years older. Thus, if he was 43 when he arrived in Egypt, he died 94 years later.

https://aish.com/duration-of-slavery-in-egypt/

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of your own almost-simultaneous other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yocheved was the daughter of Levi, Jacob’s son. She was born at the very moment when Jacob and his entire household, Levi and his wife among them, had just entered the gates of Egypt. That was in the year 2238 after Creation. Yocheved was the youngest member of the seventy souls who made up Jacob’s household.

Yocheved was brought up by her father and grandfather. For seventeen years she was together with her grandfather, for Jacob died seventeen years after his coming to Egypt. Yocheved married her nephew Amram, a grandson of her father.

Her father died when Yocheved was 93 or 94 years old, for Levi was the last of Jacob’s twelve sons to die (in the year 2331 or 2332).

https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/112040/jewish/Yocheved.htm

The Targum Yonasan ben Uziel says that Yocheved was 94 years old when Levi died.

Comment: In 1Q21, Levi was 94 years old when Amram married Jochebed who were the parents of Aaron and Moses. I don't know if if that's accepted or not.

Answer (score -1):

Yeladim = 94
Hataf = 94