# Chamisha Vetish'im - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows ninety-five?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Comment: Prev: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2903/arbaa-vetishim-mi-yodeya

Comment: next: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2934/shisha-vetishim-mi-yodeya

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Gemara in Niddah 29b discusses a complicated scenario involving a woman who miscarried, regarding which Beis Shammai hold that the woman will be required to immerse in a mikveh on various days (due to טבילה בזמנה מצוה) for a total of 95 times.

Comment: 95 dunks in the mikvah?

Comment: You're trying to make it fit the beat, right?

Comment: Hadn't thought about that.  Just making sure I understand your answer; 95 actual dunks (not "several dunks over 95 days").  Wow that's a lot!  But good point about the beat.

Comment: Yup, 95 dunks. But according to Beis Hillel it's only 35, and according to the view that tevilah b'zmanah is not a mitzvah, she requires only one tevilah at the very end.

Comment: Checkmark for surprising Shalom.

Comment: I'm just waiting for the manufacturers of nail-polish-remover, cotton swabs, nail files, etc. to start pushing to be machmir like Beis Shamai again ...

Comment: :-)  to both Isaac and Sholom.

Comment: BTW Shalom, the case discussed there is very unusual, probably more theoretical (to bring out the full extent of all the opinions) than practical.

Comment: https://dafyomi.co.il/nidah/points/ni-ps-030.htm

Answer (score 4):

There are 95 places in the Gemara where the halachah is decided according to R' Yosei. This relates Kabbalistically to the fact that the large Sanhedrin (of 72 meambers including the Nasi) and the small one (of 23) also total 95, as well as to a couple of the other 95-words that [Gershon](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2914/chamisha-vetishim-mi-yodeya/2915#2915) mentioned.

([Megaleh Amukos on Vaeschanan, explanation 191](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=11571&st=&pgnum=237))

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Megaleh_Amukot.191.1?lang=bi

Answer (score 2):

Speaking of seasonality, the word "LeDovid" appears 95 times in Tanach.

Answer (score 0):

Matza = 95
Haman = 95
Malka = 95
Yiska = 95
Yaffa = 95
HaMelech = 95
Zevulin = 95

Comment: Of these, HaMelech is by far the most common (appears nearly twice as often in Tanach as all others combined); it's seasonally appropriate; and it's textually interesting because in the Book of Esther, we're encouraged to tease out when it's Achashverosh and when it's G-d.

Comment: Also דניאל equals 95. Me'am Loez (I don't recall his source) says that this is why Daniel changed his name to Hasach, as we find in Megillas Esther - so as to have nothing in common with Haman, not even a numerical value.

Answer (score 0):

Chelbena (one of the spices in the k'tores) = 95. Also, "keis kah" (Hashem's "incomplete" throne) = 95.