# Shisha Vetish'im - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows ninety-six?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Comment: prev: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2914/chamisha-vetishim-mi-yodeya

Comment: next: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2965/shiva-vetishim-mi-yodeya

Answer (score 5, accepted):

96 is the Gematria of "Tzav"; the Masoretic note says parshas Tzav has 96 verses.  Though I think there's a note that our count has 97 or something like that?  Eh close enough ...

Comment: You beat me to it, Shalom!

Comment: Sorry.  That was really low-hanging fruit.

Comment: I'll let you take this one for 97 also. :)

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27373/759

Answer (score 6):

Yirmiyahu (52:23) describes the ornamentation of the columns Yachin and Boaz in the first Beis Hamikdash (which were destroyed by the Babylonians): "The pomegranates were 96 to the outside; all the pomegranates were 100 on the net all around."

The commentaries explain that there were actually 100 per column, but only 96 of them were visible, because the other four were embedded into the facade of the building. R' Yosei (Tosefta Ohalos 7:13) uses this to derive a general geometric principle: when a cylinder is tangent to a plane (e.g., a beam lying on the ground), 1/25 of its circumference will be hidden from view.

Answer (score 5):

There were 24 shifts of Kohanim in the Beis HaMikdash, and each shift had four cubbies or alcoves in which to store their four types of priestly garments (Rambam, Klei HaMikdash 8:8-9) -- 24 times 4 = a total of 96.

Answer (score 4):

A silver dinar weighs the equivalent of 96 grains of barley. (Rambam, Peirush HaMishnayos in the beginning of Kiddushin and in Eduyos 4:7)

Answer (score 3):

According to the Rishonim who hold that it takes 24 minutes to walk one *mil*, the time to walk four *mil* (which signifies tzeis hakochavim in Rabbeinu Tam's opinion) would be 96 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

We fast ninety-six *shaos z'maniyos* (halachic hours) over the course of a year: twelve each on four fast days and twenty-four each on two. (This excludes "extra" time: between sunset and nightfall, and *tosefes yom hakipurim*. It also excludes *taanis b'choros* and other fasts that are not widely kept.)

Answer (score 1):

Hamalach = 96

Melacha = 96

Yaffo = 96

Comment: From Parshas Chukat Numbers 20:5 ומים equals 96 "and water" (and there is no water).

Answer (score 1):

[Ezra 8:35](https://www.sefaria.org/Ezra.8.35?ven=Tanakh:_The_Holy_Scriptures,_published_by_JPS&lang=bi)

> הַ֠בָּאִ֠ים מֵֽהַשְּׁבִ֨י בְנֵֽי־הַגּוֹלָ֜ה הִקְרִ֥יבוּ עֹל֣וֹת ׀ לֵאלֹקי יִשְׂרָאֵ֗ל פָּרִ֨ים שְׁנֵים־עָשָׂ֤ר עַל־כׇּל־יִשְׂרָאֵל֙ **אֵילִ֣ים ׀ תִּשְׁעִ֣ים וְשִׁשָּׁ֗ה** כְּבָשִׂים֙ שִׁבְעִ֣ים וְשִׁבְעָ֔ה צְפִירֵ֥י חַטָּ֖את שְׁנֵ֣ים עָשָׂ֑ר הַכֹּ֖ל עוֹלָ֥ה לַה'׃ {פ}
>
> The returning exiles who arrived from captivity made burnt offerings to the God of Israel: twelve bulls for all Israel, **ninety-six rams**, seventy-seven lambs and twelve he-goats as a purification offering, all this a burnt offering to the LORD.

Answer (score 0):

In cases of need, such as a worker who needs to daven early, one can say Korbanot from 96 minutes (in Shaot Zmaniot) before HaNetz. Halacha Brurah 1:16 (based on Sh”t Yacheve Daat 2:8).