# Shiv'a Vetish'im - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows ninety-seven?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Comment: prev: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2934/shisha-vetishim-mi-yodeya

Comment: next: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2993/shemona-vetishim-mi-yodeya

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yaakov was 97 when he left the house of Lavan:

63 when he received the brachos

14 years in yeshiva

20 years by Lavan

Answer (score 4):

There are 97 chapters in Sefer Zemanim, the third book (and second-longest) of the Rambam's Mishneh Torah.

Answer (score 3):

According to those who say Rivka was 14 when she married Yitzchak, she was 97 when Yitzchak blessed Yaakov:

14 years at marriage

20 years until Yaakov was born

63 years until Yaakov received the brachos

Answer (score 2):

Zman = 97 and Yom Kippur is considered L'maalah Min H'Zman.

Answer (score 1):

As [Shalom](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/21/shalom) pointed out [elsewhere](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2934/shisha-vetishim-mi-yodeya/2937#2937), Parshas Tzav has 97 pesukim -- though the 'siman' given at the end of the parsha is the [eponymous](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/eponymous) צו, which equals 96.

Answer (score 0):

- Levi lived **97** years in Egypt (out of 137)

Daas Mikra (Shemos, vol. 1 p. 234 n. 85), where they cite Shadal's approach, they mention another interesting one, from Moshe David (Umberto) Cassuto:
See:[400 Years in Egypt (?)](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5642/400-years-in-egypt/5652#5652)

- Nedarim 32a Avraham was three years old when he recognized his creator - Hashem. Avraham lived 175 years of which he recognized his creator 172 years. Avraham gave birth to Yitzchok when he was 100 years old. Yitzchok gave birth to Yaakov when he was 60 years old. Yaakov lived 147 years. If you add the span of time that Avraham, Yitzchok, & Yaakov lived and recognized Hashem (**97 years till the birth of Yitzchok** + 60 years till the birth of Yaakov + 147 years of Yaakov) it totals 304 years. (See: [Arba'a Ushlosh Meyot - mi yodeya?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/21823/arbaa-ushlosh-meyot-mi-yodeya/21835#21835))