# Shemona Vetishim - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows ninety-eight?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Comment: prev: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2965/shiva-vetishim-mi-yodeya

Answer (score 5, accepted):

During the seven days of Sukkos, fourteen lambs were offered each day for the additional offerings (musaf) in the Beis Hamikdash, for a total of 98. These correspond to the 98 curses in the Warning (tochachah) of Deut. 28:15-68; we ask Hashem to save us from having to experience these, in the merit of these 98 offerings.

(Rashi to Num. 29:18)

Comment: Well done, sir! May God let us return to this practice this year. Chas veshalom failing that, may our prayers this Sukkot stand in for those lambs, such that God grants us a 5771 free of curses.

Answer (score 6):

After separating an average amount of *terumah* from his produce (i.e., one-fiftieth), one is left with **98%** of what he started with.

Answer (score 6):

Eli was 98 when he died after receiving a report that the aron was captured by the pelishtim.  Shmuel A 4:15-18