# Arba'a Ushlosh Meyot - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows three hundred and four?

### ?ארבעה ושלוש מאות - מי יודע

In the spirit of the song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea), please post interesting and significant Jewish facts about the number 304.

It could be devilishly hard, perhaps even more like actual work than squeezing out toothpaste, to come up with something from the lazy gematria here.

Check out [mi-yodeya-series](/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) for the previous three hundred and three entries in this ongoing series.

Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

Comment: `It could be devilishly hard, perhaps even more like actual work than squeezing out toothpaste, to come up with something from the lazy gematria here.` That would be סחיטה, not **דש**.

Comment: @ba But the `devil` would still be a `שד`.

Comment: @ba
בני בנים כבנים הם

Comment: @ba also http://www.mathwords.com/t/transitive_property_inequalities.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We are now in the midst of cycle # 304 of the 19 year moon cycle. This cycle runs from the years 5758 - 5776.

Answer (score 5):

[Nedarim 32a](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9690&st=&pgnum=67) Avraham was three years old when he recognized his creator - Hashem. Avraham lived 175 years of which he recognized his creator 172 years. Avraham gave birth to Yitzchok when he was 100 years old. Yitzchok gave birth to Yaakov when he was 60 years old. Yaakov lived 147 years. If you add the span of time that Avraham, Yitzchok, & Yaakov lived and recognized Hashem (97 years till the birth of Yitzchok + 60 years till the birth of Yaakov + 147 years of Yaakov) it totals 304 years.

Comment: Very nice! [15c