# Discrepancy in number of Pesukim in Va'eschanan

Tags: number, vaeschanan

At the end of Parshas Va'eschanan all the Chumashim I have seen [(example 1)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39840&st=&pgnum=115) [(example 2)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14360&st=&pgnum=92) [(example 3)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9617&st=&pgnum=106&hilite=) mention that there are 118 verses - Uziel Siman - as Uziel = 118. Artscroll Chumash has the same information. Yet if one counts the verses, there are actually 122. What is the reason for this discrepancy?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27373/parshas-tzav-96-pesukim

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those Chumashim are unfortunately mistaken. All old manuscripts of the Torah have listed that there are 119 verses (see clips from 8 of them [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iE92.png)). If you count the Decalogue as 10 verses, as is read in [Taam Elyon](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/c/ct/cupper10.htm), then you get 119. Problem solved.

(All those Mikraot Gedolot are probably just copying from [Daniel Bomberg's edition](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42687&st=&pgnum=408) which has this problem ([among others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mikraot_Gedolot#The_Ben_Hayyim_edition)).)

Answer (score 1):

the same thing happens in parshas yisro 72 and 75- I was told that the 10 commandments can be grouped slightly differently than originally eg lo signov lo tirzoch were possibly previously in one verse
other discrepancies in parshas Bo and Vayishlach - I don't have an answer for that :(

Comment: See הערות התמימים ואנ"ש - מוריסטאון No. 413, 5746, page 4 for discussion of this topic.

Comment: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/25722