# Why no number of p'sukim for P'kude?

Tags: number, mesorah-tradition, pekudei

Many copies of *Chumash* list, after each *parasha* (weekly reading), the number of verses in that *parasha*. By and large, they omit it for *parashas P'kude*; why?

(And if the answer is that they copy the information from some version of the *m'sora*, which omits the information for *P'kude*, my question is transferred to that *m'sora*: why does it omit the information for *P'kude*?)

Comment: http://www.col.org.il/%D7%97%D7%93%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%97%D7%91%D7%93_%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%93_%D7%94%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%9F_%D7%A9%D7%9C_%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%AA_%D7%A4%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%93%D7%99_%D7%9E%D7%97%D7%A7%D7%A8_81234.html

Comment: The copy I have in my bag (one volume cheap edition that I bought for shnayim mikra on the train, not a particularly notable edition) has the number of pesukim listed but without a mnemonic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Aharon Ahrend has a detailed article in Rabbi Mordechai Breuer's Festschrift (vol. 1 p. 157) titled "The Mneumotechnical Notes of the Numbers of Verses in the Torah Portions" where he goes through the history of these notes. Turns out Pekudei's mnemonic was first erroneously dropped in the [Venice Mikraot Gedolot](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42687&st=&pgnum=238) along with [Toldot's](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42687&st=&pgnum=69&hilite=) and [Haazinu's](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42687&st=&pgnum=461). This edition had a number of other errors in regards these notes which he details (such as [Vayikra](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42687&st=&pgnum=248) getting the mnemonic צו or [Lekh Lekha](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42687&st=&pgnum=44) getting מכנדב instead of מכנדבי). In later editions the mnemonics for Bechukotai, Vayechi, Yitro were each dropped too. An edition in 1859 (which had some of its own errors, like using מכנדיב instead of [מכנדבי](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94:%D7%A2%D7%96%D7%A8%D7%90_%D7%99_%D7%9E)) added them all back in except Pekudei's, and that's why you often still see it missing.

In old texts we can still find mnemonics for its 92 verses such as [עזיה](http://cudl.lib.cam.ac.uk/view/MS-ADD-00652/138) or [סבכי](https://digitalcollections.nypl.org/items/510d47df-c964-a3d9-e040-e00a18064a99).

Comment: Interestingly he shows that the earliest lists of these mnemonics use exclusively names of people from Tanakh as spelled in Tanakh with the given explanation of having some person to metaphorically "guard the number" so that nothing is left out. That's why they regularly use such obscure names in Ezra or Chronicles, since it's not easy to find names of important people with the right numerical value.

Comment: Does he suggest a reason why it was left out? Like it was an oversight perhaps? The OP seems pretty adamant that he wants a reason for the omission in this type of answer.

Comment: @user6591 As indicated the edition was riddled with errors. Call it sloppiness. Call it oversight. It doesn't seem there's anything deeper than that.

Comment: Fair enough. +1.

Comment: @user6591 We can speculate that the note for number of verses in the whole book confused someone or something like that. That could explain Bechukotai and Vaychi getting dropped later too. But that'd just be me making things up.

Answer (score 9):

From [Chabad.org](http://www.chabad.org.il/Magazines/Article.asp?ArticleID=3824&CategoryID=957) this question was once asked by Rabbi Alexander-Sender Yudasin to the Lubavitcher Rabbi Zatzal. The Rabbi said that perhaps since the Siman was = the words "בלי כל" the original Siman said 
"בלי כל ֿ סימן". A publisher who misunderstood took it that there was no Siman and left it out, thus it was not in future editions.

> הרב אלכסנדר-סנדר יודאסין, שהיה רב בתל-אביב, שיגר מכתב אל הרבי
>   מליובאוויטש ושאל מדוע בסוף פרשת פקודי בחומשים לא מופיע 'סימן' לפסוקי
>   הפרשה (מילה או כמה מילים שהגימטרייה שלהן היא כמניין הפסוקים), שלא כמו
>   בפרשות האחרות.
>
> "הרבי השיב לו תשובה מפתיעה בפשטותה הגאונית. וכך כתב: "יש לחפש בדפוסים
>   הראשונים, כי לדעתי אין זה אלא השמטת המדפיס, ונמשך הדבר כן גם אצל שאר
>   המדפיסים שבאו אחריו"
>
> "לאחר מכן מציע הרבי הסבר מדוע השמיט זאת המדפיס: בפרשת פקודי יש תשעים
>   ושניים פסוקים. הגימטרייה של המילים "בלי כל" היא תשעים ושניים. ייתכן
>   איפה שהיה כתוב "בלי כל ֿ סימן". לאחר מכן בא מדפיס ('הבחור הזעצער') שלא
>   הבין את משמעות הדבר, אלא תפס את העניין כפשוטו, שאין כאן שום סימן,
>   והחליט שאם כך, אין טעם לציין זאת"...
>
> - See more at: http://www.chabad.org.il/Magazines/Article.asp?ArticleID=3824&CategoryID=957#sthash.LGIMrAdq.dpuf

Comment: Brilliant, especially since according to my pocket chumash, which *does* list the number of pesukim it's 92.

Comment: Do we have any example of this missing link (a Chumash that _does_ says בלי כל סימן)? This seems highly improbable.

Answer (score 0):

I recall reading the the menmonic בלי כל  Bli Kol is a remez/allusion to the posuk in the Tochacha of Ki Savo at 28:55 which says that מבלי השאיר לו כל, that a person will eat his child and leave nothing over. So it is alluding to a Klallah that nothing will be left. Not sure why the middle words are left out except that the point is brought across without the additional words and , obviously, to make it equal 92. It would seem to imply that Pikudei which lists the materials for the Mishkan and lists the clothing of the Kohanim and contains the setting up of the Mishkan and the fact that the Glory of Hashem filled it, means that the Yidden were forgiven for the Chet Ha Egel. So the Kellalah of Bli Kol was avoided. Perhaps the printer made a mistake but perhaps he left it out on purpose because its not a good siman if you just refer to the curse. But if you refer to the curse being uprooted, than its ok. All in the intention of the reader.

Additionally, a few Posukim before at 28:47 the Torah says that because you did not serve Hashem correctly when you had מרב כל therefore the punishments will come. Seems that Bli Kol is the opposite of Merov Kol. Same idea, you dodged the bullet of Bli Kol with the building and dedication of the Mishkan but now we see that a Bli Kol is the Midah Geneged Midah of not serving Hashem when you had Merov Kol. My thought- not sure if its any good.

Comment: This sounds like a comment to @gershongold's answer