# What is the total amount and count of pesukim in the Torah?

Tags: number, mesorah-tradition, pentateuch-chumash

After much research, both on Israeli websites ([here](http://torah.125mb.com/)) and other locations, I have yet to figure out what the total amount of pesukim there are in the Torah.  I've even physically counted the pesukim in Tikum Simanim and came up with 5,846.  Yet other say 5,845.  I realize that the verse [35:22](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.35.22?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) in Vayishlach is an issue, but even then it would be 5,847!!!  Also need to consider Ta'am Elyon and Ta'am Tachton, both in Vayishlach and in the Aseret Hadibrot (in Yitro and V'etchanan). Parashat Tzav has 97 pesukim as per main sources as well.

For those who question why this is important; it is the result of something I heard that the G'ra wrote in Sifrei D'tzniusa that pesukim of the Torah correlate to the Jewish years.

As an aside note, I have found in my research that the cute gematria words used to remember the amount of pesukim has it source from a non-Jewish person, although numbering of verses were first utilized in Hebrew by Rabbi Isaac Nathan ben Kalonymus, who begun in 1438 and finished in 1448, his Hebrew Biblical Concordance  called, "Meir Nativ."  The Meir Nativ, with its complete introduction, was first published in Venice on the 26th of Tishrei, 5284 (October 15, 1523) and printed by Daniel Bomberg, a Christian printer, born in Antwerp.

Comment: I'm not sure that there is a complete agreement on the number of psukim, since you mentioned some of the nuances in what's a verse. I think that in addition to the list you mentioned, there may be a dispute in those places having an etnachta in the middle of a parsha, which occurs in about 5 places. I don't know if these are counted as 1 or 2 verses. +1 for an interesting question.

Comment: BTW, so that we know, usually the term "count" and "amount" are synonymous. Is there something else that you're looking for? Otherwise, I suggest you use the term "number" which would be the correct term to use in the question title.

Comment: I see that you said Breishit 35:22 is an "issue". I looked it up just now, and yes, it's b/c there's a dispute regarding any verse having a parsha break at a trope note other than *sof pasuk*. There are about 5 such occurrences in the Torah. The question is does the *sof pasuk* determine the end of a verse, or does the end of a parsha automatically end a verse regardless of what note it occurs? In these cases, all breaks occur at an *etnachta*. There's prob. a Masoretic meaning behind this, but I don't know what it is. Anyone know?

Comment: @DanF I've never heard of the dispute you mention in the last comment.

Comment: Welcome to the site Shmuel! Consider taking the following two minute [tour](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about the site. Hope to see you around.

Comment: @DoubleAA Dispute is prob. not the correct word, but I couldn't think of a better one. Point is, different Chumashim that I've seen count it as either 1 pasuk or 2 separate ones.

Comment: @DanF I've never ever seen a Chumash count it as two.

Comment: If one looks at the end of parashat Yitro, they will notice that the parasha should have 72 pesukim.  How is this even possible?  It's totally off no matter how you count it.

Comment: @ShmuelGoldstein: it's 72 pesukim if you count each dibrah as one posuk (instead of them spanning 13 pesukim), so that you have 27 pesukim in perek 18, 25 in perek 19, and 20 in perek 20.

Comment: DanF, I believe you really meant the dispute of a pasuk being left with a pesucha (open paragraph space) such as in Breisheet, 35:22.  An esnachta doesn't cause an issue as such that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 2):

I have an article explaining this at [Count of Pesukim in each Parsha](https://sabbahillel.blogspot.com/2016/01/count-of-pesukim-in-each-parsha.html)

The counts were taken from the Art Scroll Chumash notes at the end of each parsha. Note that while the masoretic count of Tzav is 96, A physical count of Pesukim shows 97.

An interesting point is that one could say that

The Masoretic note at the end of the parashah is "Tzav Siman" without the number of verses. The Masoretes specifically omitted the number of verses, because from the first word Tzav on the 2nd pasuk it is 96 verses exactly. Luckily that precise note was kept.

Pekudei does not have a note at the end of the parsha but the Art Scroll commentary says the edition of the Chumash printed with the Malbim's commentary.gives it as 92 (which matches the physical count in the chumash)

However we find that  R Menachem Mendel Schneerson z"l (1902-1994; the Lubavitcher Rebbe) was once asked why, and he responded as follows:

It is necessary to check older prints of the chumash, for in my opinion, this originates from a printers omission, which was later copied by other printers. Perhaps the original siman consisted of the phrase bli kol / without any [see Devarim 28:55], which has a gematria of 92. Perhaps a young printers apprentice saw the phrase bli kol siman / without any siman and misunderstood its meaning, so that Parashat Pekudei was, in fact, left without any siman. (Quoted in Otzrot Tzaddikei Ugeonei Hadorot)

Yisro appears to use the taamei elyon count (10 pesukim) instead of the taamei tachton count (13 pesukim) for the total given at the comment at the end. This is based on comparing the note to the physical count as printed in the Chumash.

The mesorah note for Vayeilech of 70 appears for the combined parshiyos of Nitzavim and Vayeilech. This means 40 in Nitzavim and 30 in Vayeilech

The Art Scroll (Stone Edition) Mesorah note for Bo says:

> ק"ה פסוקים. ימנ"ה סימן: This Masoretic note means: There are 105
> verses in the *Sidrah*, numerically corresponding to the mnemonic
> יִמְנֶה *he will count*.
>
> This alludes to the law that each person must count himself as part of
> a group that brings the *pesach*-offerings (*R' David Feinstein*)

@DoubleAA points out that the classical simanim are the names of people in Tanach so it would be the son of אשר.

It is possible that [Bo 13:1](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9874#v=1) is treated by the mesorah count as part of 13:2 as shown by the trop. Note that the English translation ends with a comma not a period.

> וַיְדַבֵּ֥ר יְהֹוָ֖ה אֶל־משֶׁ֥ה לֵּאמֹֽר
>
> 1 The Lord spoke to Moses, saying,

Parsha counts:

| Parsha | Count | Sefer | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Breishis | 146 | 146 | 146 |
| Noach | 153 | 299 | 299 |
| Lech Lecha | 126 | 425 | 425 |
| Vayera | 147 | 572 | 572 |
| Chayei Sara | 105 | 677 | 677 |
| Toldos | 106 | 783 | 783 |
| Vayetzei | 148 | 931 | 931 |
| Vayishlach | 154 | 1085 | 1085 |
| Vayeshev | 112 | 1197 | 1197 |
| Miketz | 146 | 1343 | 1343 |
| Vayigash | 106 | 1449 | 1449 |
| Vaychi | 85 | 1534 | 1534 |
| Shmos | 124 | 124 | 1658 |
| Vaeira | 121 | 245 | 1779 |
| Bo | 105 | 350 | 1884 |
| Beshalach | 116 | 466 | 2000 |
| Yisro | 72 | 538 | 2072 |
| Mishpatim | 118 | 656 | 2190 |
| Terumah | 96 | 752 | 2286 |
| Tetzaveh | 101 | 853 | 2387 |
| Ki Sisa | 139 | 992 | 2526 |
| Vayakhel | 122 | 1114 | 2648 |
| Pekudei | 92 | 1206 | 2740 |
| Vayikra | 111 | 111 | 2851 |
| Tzav | 96 | 207 | 2947 |
| Shmini | 91 | 298 | 3038 |
| Tazria | 67 | 365 | 3105 |
| Metzora | 90 | 455 | 3195 |
| Acharei Mos | 80 | 535 | 3275 |
| Kedoshim | 64 | 599 | 3339 |
| Emor | 124 | 723 | 3463 |
| Behar | 57 | 780 | 3520 |
| Bechukosai | 78 | 858 | 3598 |
| Bamidbar | 159 | 159 | 3757 |
| Naso | 176 | 335 | 3933 |
| Beha'aloscha | 136 | 471 | 4069 |
| Shlach | 119 | 590 | 4188 |
| Korach | 95 | 685 | 4283 |
| Chukas | 87 | 772 | 4370 |
| Balak | 104 | 876 | 4474 |
| Pinchas | 168 | 1044 | 4642 |
| Mattos | 112 | 1156 | 4754 |
| Masei | 132 | 1288 | 4886 |
| Devarim | 105 | 105 | 4991 |
| Va'eschanan | 119 | 224 | 5110 |
| Eikev | 111 | 335 | 5221 |
| Re'eh | 126 | 461 | 5347 |
| Shoftim | 97 | 558 | 5444 |
| Ki Seitzei | 110 | 668 | 5554 |
| Ki Savo | 122 | 790 | 5676 |
| Nitzavim | 40 | 830 | 5716 |
| Vayeilech | 30 | 860 | 5746 |
| Ha'azinu | 52 | 912 | 5798 |
| Vezos Habrachah | 41 | 953 | 5839 |

Comment: "It is necessary to check older prints of the chumash" Indeed he was right about that, because the rest of his speculation ended up being completely false. If you're curious what the older editions actually reveal (as he was) you should read https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/82887/759 (and please don't keep quoting these mistaken speculations in public without explaining the truth as well; it's highly misleading)

Comment: The question was how many verses are there. Did you verify every number being posted? So the source for this answer is essentially "I counted"? How did you pick to count regarding the Tachton or Elyon number?

Comment: @DoubleAA According to the counts, and a note from you, *the individual parsha mesorah uses the taamei elyon while the book total uses the taamei tachton* in the Art Scroll counts for Yisro and Vaeschanan. The difference in each set is three, 72 to 75 in Yisro and 119 to 122 in Vaeschanan.

Comment: There should be 106 pesukim in Bo? !!!!  Count them!

Comment: 29+10+51+16=106 !!!  Add it again.

Comment: You are correct in adding the numbers. However, look at the trop of [Bo 13:1](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9874) It is possible that וַיְדַבֵּ֥ר יְהֹוָ֖ה אֶל־משֶׁ֥ה לֵּאמֹֽר is being treated as part of the next pasuk. Since I am not an expert in the trop, I am unable to say if this is true or not. @ShmuelGoldstein Perhaps that is the reason that the end note says 105, citing Rav Dovid Feinstein for the siman. Note that the English translation ends with a , not a period.

Comment: The trop in this pasuk are normal and is considered one pasuk.  Again, this must be a mistake. 
וַיֹּ֤אמֶר יְהֹוָה֙ אֶל־משֶׁ֔ה בֹּ֖א אֶל־פַּרְעֹ֑ה כִּֽי־אֲנִ֞י הִכְבַּ֤דְתִּי אֶת־לִבּוֹ֙ וְאֶת־לֵ֣ב עֲבָדָ֔יו לְמַ֗עַן שִׁתִ֛י אֹֽתֹתַ֥י אֵ֖לֶּה בְּקִרְבּֽוֹ:

Comment: @ShmuelGoldstein You cited [Bo 10:1](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9871). I cited [Bo 13:1](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9874). I do not follow the point of your commnt.

Answer (score 1):

The Gemara Kiddushin 30a says that there are 5,888 verses in the Torah.

Regarding discrepancies and other issues you raised, see the following article which discusses in length and detail: http://www.hakirah.org/Vol%207%20EpsteinGreenberger.pdf

Comment: It is certainly interesting that the author of this article in Hakira also acknowledges the blatant issue, but says as follows: 

"Most Chumashim indicate that there are 5,845 verses and offer a numerically equivalent “siman,” but an actual  count shows 5,846 verses. A discussion of this type of discrepancy, which sometimes also appears in the number of verses in a parashah and the parashah’s siman, is beyond the scope of this paper."

Comment: The Gemara probably originally said 8,888 verses (meant Midrashicly) but was later 'corrected' to what someone thought may have been intended. For instance we have Geonic responsa where they ask "How could it be 8,888?" and the answer is it's not.