# Vilna Gaon on a year corresponding to a verse in the Torah

Tags: sources-mekorot, vilna-gaon

Rabbi Anava said in a [shiur](https://vimeo.com/511449886#t=1h13m51s) that:

> The Vilna Gaon says that there are 5,845 verses in the Torah.
> Additionally, he says that every year from creation corresponds to one
> verse in the Torah.

Does anyone know if this can be found in a sefer that the Vilna Gaon wrote?

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/62455/what-is-the-total-amount-and-count-of-pesukim-in-the-torah

Comment: There is no such Gr"a