# Pesukim corresponding to years

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah

Just heard that apparently there’s 5845 pesukim in the Torah, and the Vilna gaon used to say that each pasuk corresponds to its corresponding year. So the first pasuk is somehow related to the events of the year 1, and so on.

First of all, according to the vilna gaon does he hold that the “max” number of years is 5845?
Secondly, they said that people have proven and showed how certain years have matched up with their pesukim. Does anyone have any examples of this?

Comment: A good example is בראשית ברא אלהים את השמים ואת הארץ

Comment: Related/dupe: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/120138/27180

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/67516/where-is-the-source-for-assigning-a-pasuk-to-each-year-since-creation?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: A lot of stuff said in the name of the Gra is made up, unfortunately. Unless you can find it in a reliable source, I would discount it.