Genesis 35:22 read twice with different trop?
Page 40 in my eish matzleach tikun shows Genesis 35:22 read two times with different trop according to the note at the bottom of the page.
Eight words in this passuck have 2 trop signals.
The Simanim tikun shows only 1 trop for each word.
The purple Chumash (rabbi Kaplan) shows 2 trops on some of the words without explanation.
Which groups have the custom to read the sentence twice using different trop ?

The complication re: the מעשה ראובן section comes from the fact that there are two divergent sets of trop based on taam tachton and taam elyon (similar to the more well known tachton/elyon divergence for aseres hadibros). In one set there is a sof pasuk (siluk) in the middle to treat this as 2 pesukim instead of one.  In standard Chumashim these two sets of trop are often overlayed onto each other which creates confusion - Also see the following which touches upon this issue - https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/62455/what-is-the-total-amount-and-count-of-pesukim-in-the-torah

How common is it to read the sentence twice ? Who has this custom to read it twice ?
