# אלקים בגימטריא הטבע and not טבע?

Tags: theology, science, gematria-numerology

There's a oft quoted saying that "אלקים בגימטריא הטבע." Why is it  הטבע and not טבע? Isn't it "cheating" to add the extra  "ה"?

Comment: Define cheating. If you're just trying to illustrate a point (that God can be found in nature) and not prove it, then I would call it "artistic license".

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/2724/759

Comment: I've heard the same thing about השטן and 364 (i.e. every day except one)

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/53052/759

Comment: Unless we have some rigorous definition of cheating, this seems opinion based.

Comment: @mevaqesh That's not the point. I'm pretty sure we all understand what Joshua meant...I don't think this question needs a "rigorous definition of cheating."

Comment: @Shokhet I agree that we understand what he meant. But what counts as cheating is opinion based. For example, is trying variant spellings using gematriya (which arent grammatically incorrect) until finding a hit, cheating. Who gets to decide what counts as cheating? Hence POB.