# What is the connection between the natural world and sinking? (טבע)

Tags: sources-mekorot, words, hebrew, beshalach, natural-phenomenon

Do any commentators explain a connection between the shared root of the word "טבע" for sinking (as in [Shemos 15:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.15.4?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) - טֻבְּעוּ בְיַם) and the natural world of טבע?

Comment: טבע meaning "nature" is relatively recent - within the last 1000 years.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53052/source-of-the-word-teva-for-nature

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Source of the word "teva" for nature](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53052/source-of-the-word-teva-for-nature)

Comment: @kouty I only see such a reference in a comment, why do you think that it is a duplicate?

Answer (score 3):

The [Shem miShmuel](https://www.sefaria.org/Shem_MiShmuel%2C_Shmini.1.4?vhe=Sefer_Shem_Mishmuel,_Piotrkow,_1927-1934&lang=bi) answers your question, he says:

> ואדמו"ר זצללה"ה הכהן הגדול מאלכסנדר אמר כי לשון טבע הוא מלשון טובע
> בנהר, שאדם צריך שמירה שלא יטבע בגשמיות

Translation (I do not know how to translate the abbreviated titles):

> "...said: Because the word טבע (nature) is from the word טובע
> (drowning) in a stream, that a person needs gaurding in order not to
> drown in physicality."

I understand him to be saying that nature represents the natural physical world, which if a person is not careful, he will find himself drowning in.

Comment: The abbreviations stand for אדוני מורי ורבי זכר צדיק לברכה לחיי העולם הבא

Answer (score 2):

This [website](https://www.biblicalhebrewetymology.com/forum-1/general-klly/for-some-reason-we-tend-to-refer-to-nature-as-tb-yet-upon-close-examination-this-word-does-not-appear-in-tanakh-in-that-meaning-so-from) notes a connection and writes as follows:

> The term טבע to denote “nature” is derived from:
> [Prov. 8:25](https://www.sefaria.org/Proverbs.8.25?lang=bi)– Before the mountains were sunk within the water;
>
> [Metz. David](https://www.sefaria.org/Proverbs.8.25?lang=bi&p2=Metzudat_David_on_Proverbs.8.25.1&lang2=bi)… sunk in the sense of established/planted;
>
> [Ibn Ezra](https://www.sefaria.org/Proverbs.8.25?lang=bi&with=Ibn%20Ezra&lang2=en)… as in: on what were its sockets sunk (הטבעו), or who laid its cornerstone ([Job 38:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Job.38.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)).
>
> RSRH Ex. 15:4(paraphrased) – טבע means sinking into a substance which surrounds and traps. Hence טבעת (e.g. [Esth. 8:8](https://www.sefaria.org/Esther.8.8?lang=bi))… signet ring [see also Yerios Shlomo 1:61a].
>
> רשר“ה שמות טו ד ד“ה טֻבְּעוּ בְיַם סוּף – 'טבע' מורה בכל מקום על שקיעת דבר בתוך חומר מוצק הסוגר עליו ומחזיק בו מכל צד…מכאן גם טבעת.
>
> [גם י“ש מעיר על כך]: י“ש א:סא. – נקראת 'טבעת' ע“ש הטביעה שהיא טובעת בחומר וזפת החתימה, כמו: וחתמו בטבעת המלך (אסתר ח:ח). ולפי שחותם הטבעת הוא בצורת עגול חלול כדי שיוכל להכניס את האצבע ויהיה מצוי תמיד לבעליו בעת הצורך. מזה נקרא כל דבר עגול וחלול בשם 'טבעת' אף כשאינו עשוי לפעל החתימה. כמו:ארבע טבעת זהב (שמ‘כה:יב).
>
> [לשון 'טבע' (במובן “חוקי היקום“) מציינת שקיעה וקבעיות. אולם יש לה גם משמעות של שקיעה שלילית, שהרי כל בריאה ביקום גורלו לחזור לקדמותו, היינו לשקוע ולטבוע]: משלי ח:כה– בְּטֶרֶם הָרִים הָטְבְּעוּ; מצ“ד – בטרם הרים הטבעו – עד לא נטבעו ונקבע וההרים בארץ; אב“ע – בטרם הרים הטבעו – כמו על מה אדניה הטבעו ושניהם עיקרם מלשון: טֻבְּעוּ בְיַם סוּף, והטעם על יסודותם הטבועים בעמקי המים; איוב לח:ו– עַל מָה אֲדָנֶיהָ הָטְבָּעוּ; מלבי“ם – על מה אדניה הטבעו – מצייר אותה כאהל ומשכן שהקרשים מוטבעים על אדנים, כן הארץ עומדת על בלימה,ועל מה הטבעו?; ש“א יז:מט– וַיַּךְ אֶת הַפְּלִשְׁתִּי אֶל מִצְחוֹ וַתִּטְבַּע הָאֶבֶן בְּמִצְחוֹ; מצ“צ (שם): ותטבע – מלשון טביעה.

So from this, I guess one can conclude from the Metzudos Dovid and Ibn Ezra that nature to a certain degree, is something that is entrenched and 'sunk' if you like, into our world. It is part of the established order of the world that Hashem created.

Answer (score 0):

Gad Ben-Ami Sarfatti wrote an article for the [Academy of Hebrew Language](https://hebrew-academy.org.il/) in-depth on this point, give it a look:

https://hebrew-academy.org.il/wp-content/uploads/Gad-B.-Sarfatti-Hashem-Teva.pdf