# Why is וַיְהִי בִּנְסעַ the minimum Sefer Torah size?

Tags: shabbat, talmud-gemara, sefer-torah

The gemara in shabbos with regards to saving scrolls says that the scrolls has to 85 letters, the gemara says it has to be the same as וַיְהִי בִּנְסעַ if it has 85 letter you can save it. Why specifically this section of the Torah?

What does the number 85 represent that it is used to say that this is how many letters you need for it to be a Torah Scroll?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2700/759

Comment: See https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1231/759 If you have another question, you can [ask](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) it separately.

Answer (score 6):

[Rashi to Shabbat 115b](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Shabbat.115b.4.1?lang=bi) explains that it is because these two verses are considered a complete book of the Torah on their own (quoting the *gemara* later on [116a](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.116a.1?lang=bi)).

Comment: Also note the weird shaped Nuns aroud this verse, that act as parentheses.

Comment: @Joel K. Yes I know that. I was asking why specifically that posuk?

Comment: @Russel Why specifically that posuk what?

Comment: @JoelK As in that posuk of וַיְהִי בִּנְסעַ, besides from what Rashi says. Why is that the paradigm of being the minimum to be called a sefer torah?

Comment: @Russel Because it's the shortest of the seven 'sefarim' which comprise the Torah

Comment: @Joel K That's not what I am asking. I am asking out of the posukim in the torah why specifically is that one called a sefer?

Comment: @Russel I read your question above, and as far as I can tell what you said in your comment is not what you asked.

Comment: Until this point in Bamidbar, the Jews get their marching orders and things are on track for a smooth, orderly journey to the Promised Land. Just after this they start complaining ... and the entire book shifts to dealing with the problems. Rabbi Joseph Dov Soloveichik therefore suggested that this mini-book divides the Book of Bamidbar (Numbers) that could have been, from the one that instead turned out. (Or something to that effect; it's in a piece from Rabbi Etshalom, and also heard from a rabbi who heard it in Boston.)