# Where does the custom of a second "bar mitzvah" at 83 come from?

Tags: minhag, age, bar-bas-bat-mitzvah

I have noticed more 83 year old men celebrating their second bar mitzvahs, and cannot find any source for this.  Is it a new custom?  Does it have any basis in pre-20th century practice?

Comment: cmose, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for bringing your question here! I hope you get useful answers to this question and that you'll also look around the site and find other material that interests you, perhaps including our 30 other [tag:bar-mitzvah] questions.

Comment: The first time I heard of this concept, was back in 1999 when Kirk Douglas had a second "Bar Mitzvah" which was well covered by the media. (He has since had a third בר מצוה!)

Answer (score 10):

The rationale behind it is that Tehillim describes a lifetime as seventy years in the verse

> ימי שנותינו בהם שבעים שנה ואם בגבורות שמונים שנה

(90:10.) Thus -- the reasoning goes -- 83 is 13 years into your "second lifetime" which is as good an excuse for a kiddush as any. I do not know of any source for it prior to the twentieth century or of any book of halacha or official minhagim that quotes it, but that doesn't mean anything.

Comment: Is that your own reasoning or you heard it somewhere?  Either way, it's cute. +1

Comment: I heard it from several people, mostly people celebrating their own second bar mitzvahs

Comment: So when we all Gd-willing hit 93, on our way to many more years, do we make a 3rd bar mitzvah? +1

Comment: I would guess so. שנזכה!

Comment: @BabySeal No, it would be every 70 years since the Tehillim says you live 70 years Therefore, you a reborn Jew, and at 83 you are 13. My father always asks the question if a 70 year need to get recircumscised?

Comment: It's a cute idea, but I've always been a little confused by the practice. Why do we choose this particular milestone in the "second lifetime" to celebrate? It's not like someone becomes patur from mitzvot from 70 to 83.

Comment: @BabySeal it might be at 133 (120 + 13) or 153 (70 + m70 +13). However, it is more of a joking reference.