# How old was Moshe at the splitting of the sea?

Tags: moshe-rabbeinu, age, yetziat-mitzrayim

How old was Moshe at the splitting of the sea?

I'm estimating 43 years old or more because he left Mitzrayim went bake out of mitzrayim thats why

Comment: See http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8438

Comment: I'm not sure what the reasoning here is-- to me, the part after 'becose' seems incoherent.

Answer (score 4):

Moshe Rabbeinu turned 80 on 7 Adar before the Exodus and the splitting of the Sea was 22 Nisan (The next month)

[Shmos Va'eira 7:7](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9868#v=7)

> וּמשֶׁה בֶּן שְׁמֹנִים שָׁנָה וְאַהֲרֹן בֶּן שָׁלשׁ וּשְׁמֹנִים שָׁנָה
>   בְּדַבְּרָם אֶל פַּרְעֹה:
>
> And Moses was eighty years old, and Aaron was eighty three years old
>   when they spoke to Pharaoh.

Actually this is interpreted to mean in his 80th year (after his 79th birthday).

Seder Hadorot tells us that Moshe Rabbeinu was born in the year 2368.

It then tells us that G-d spoke to Moshe at the burning bush on the 15th of Nissan in the year 2447. This would mean that Moshe had just turned 79 a little over a month before, on the 7th of Adar. Moshe then goes to talk to Pharoah when he is 79.

The Exodus from Egypt was a year later, on the 15th of Nissan in the year 2448, when Moshe had recently turned 80.

http://www.chabad.org/parshah/article_cdo/aid/814562/jewish/Interpolated-Translation.htm#footnoteRef34a814562

> Moses was [ten months short of] 80 years old and Aaron was 83 years
>   old when they spoke to Pharaoh in the year 2447.

Answer (score 3):

According to The Jewish Timeline Encyclopedia, Moshe was born in 2368 from creation and the people crossed the Sea of Reeds in 2448. That would make Moshe 80.