# What is known about Asaph son of Berechiah?

Tags: historical-figures, book-of-chronicles

Is Asaph ben Berechiah the person mentioned in 1 Chronicles 16?

What else do we know about him?

Answer (score 2):

> Asaph ben Berechiah (11th-10th cent BCE) Israelite musician. He was one of the Levites appointed by David to supervise music in the Sanctuary. Psalms 50 and 73-83 are attributed to him. The sons of Asaph were singers in the Temple during the reign of the kings of Judah (10th-6th cent, BCE) and at the time of Ezra and Nehemiah.

([source](http://jewish_bio.enacademic.com/200/Asaph_ben_Berechiah))

Answer (score 1):

To your first question, yes, the Asaf mentioned in 1 Chronicles 16 is Asaf ben Berachiah.

To your second question:

Asaf was [a prophet](https://www.sefaria.org.il/II_Chronicles.29.30?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=bi) (see also [here](https://www.sefaria.org.il/I_Chronicles.25.1?lang=bi)) and [the head of the meshorerim](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Nehemiah.12.46?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi) [from the Levite branch of Gershon](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Malbim_on_I_Chronicles.6.29.1?vhe=Malbim_on_I_Chronicles_--_Wikisource&lang=bi&p2=I_Chronicles.6.24&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=bi) during the time of King David. When comparing the number of generations of ancestors of the three heads of the meshorerim (Asaf, Heiman and Yedutun/Eitan) - based on the assumption that each name represents one generation - it seems that Asaf was the oldest of the three. Asaf's descendants continued serving both [in the First Temple](https://www.sefaria.org.il/I_Chronicles.25.2?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi) and [in the Second](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ezra.2.41?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi). Asaf composed several chapters of Psalms: [50](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Psalms.50.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), [73](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Psalms.73.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=bi), [74](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Psalms.74.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=bi), [75](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Psalms.75.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=bi), [76](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Psalms.76.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=bi), [77](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Psalms.77.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=bi), [78](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Psalms.78.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=bi), [79](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Psalms.79.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=bi), [80](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Psalms.80.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=bi), [81](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Psalms.81.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=bi), [82](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Psalms.82.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=bi) and [83](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Psalms.83.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=bi).