# Esrim Ushlosh Meyot - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows three hundred twenty?

### ?עשרים ושלוש מאות - מי יודע

In the spirit of the song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea), please post interesting and significant Jewish facts about the number 320.

Let the lips of the Kohanim remain free of lazy gematria.

Check out [mi-yodeya-series](/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) for the previous three hundred nineteen entries in this ongoing series.

Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per Rambam Hilchos Shekalim 1:2 mentioned in [Shekel HaHodesh](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49937&st=&pgnum=11&hilite=) the amount of a Shekel mentioned in the Torah weighs 320 Seora.

Answer (score 4):

[*Avraham* 'should' have died at age 180.](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8220#showrashi=true&v=30) From that time until the exodus from Egypt was 320 years.
(Quick calculation: The exodus was [400 years from *Yitzchak*'s birth](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8210#v=13), [so 500 from *Avraham*'s](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8216#v=5), and 500−180=320.)

Answer (score 2):

[עזרא‎ 2:32](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt35a02.htm#32) discusses those that returned from Bavel. The Bnai Charim were 320:

> בני חרם שלש מאות ועשרים

Answer (score 2):

Since we count [400 years from *Yitzchak*'s birth](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8210#v=13) to the exodus from Egypt and [eighty from *Moshe*'s](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8438#answers), there were 320 years from *Yitzchak*'s birth to *Moshe*'s.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this OU article](http://www.ou.org/judaism-101/glossary/anshei-knesset-hagedolah/), the Anshei Kenesset Hagedolah led the Jewish people for approximately 320 years, from about 520 BCE, at the end of the Biblical period, to about 200 BCE, at the start of the Talmudic period.

Comment: "approximately 320 years" That's kinda weak, no? The Jews were also in Egypt for _approximately_ that long.

Comment: @DoubleAA, yes.