# Echad Ve'esrim Ushlosh Meyot - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows three hundred twenty-one?

### ?אחד ועשרים ושלוש מאות - מי יודע

In the spirit of the song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea), please post interesting and significant Jewish facts about the number 321.

Answers that only contain lazy gematria may be avoided like fire.

Check out [mi-yodeya-series](/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) for the previous three hundred twenty entries in this ongoing series.

Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

Comment: "avoided _like fire_"? It should be something _that every one_ of us can do!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are at most 321 days on which work is permitted per year, for those who live outside Israel. This occurs in a [leap year starting on Shabbos, where Cheshvan and Kislev each have 30 days](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%AA_%D7%96%D7%A9%D7%94).

```
 385 days in the year
- 55 Shabbasos
- 13 days of Yom Tov
+  4 days of Yom Tov and Shabbos, which were double counted:
                                  Rosh Hashanah, Succos, Shemini Atzeres, and the 2nd day of Shavuos
----
 321 workdays
```

Comment: I originally posted this answer for 320, where I forgot to account for the 2nd day of Shavuos. http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/34026/esrim-ushlosh-meyot-mi-yodeya/34880

Comment: You count Yom Tov and not Chol HaMoed, yet both have some Melachot which are forbidden and some which are permitted.

Comment: @DoubleAA According to the majority of Rishonim, on Chol HaMoed all work is allowed from the Torah, as opposed to Yom Tov.  So it is a correct number on a Biblical level.

Comment: @YEZ Is Yom Tov Sheni Biblical??? And I don't think you should be dismissing those who hold work on Chol HaMoed is Biblical so easily...

Comment: @DoubleAA That is true, but the prohibitions of Chol HaMoed are not in terms of Melacha according to the overwhelming majority of Rishonim.  They are just to make Chol HaMoed distinct and not set aside for getting things done.

Answer (score 1):

In the 321st year of the third millennium [AM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anno_Mundi), [Gad ben Ya'akov Avinu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gad_%28son_of_Jacob%29) passed away at the age of 125.<sup>1</sup>

In the 321st year of the fourth millennium AM, the prophet [Yirmeyahu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeremiah) delivered the prophecy about the Destruction described in [Yirmeyahu 25](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16022). In the same year, he dictated a cautionary written work (either a large part of his [eponymous book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Jeremiah) or [Eicha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eicha)) only to have King [Yehoyakim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jehoiakim) burn it up dismissively, as described in [Yirmeyahu 36](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16033).<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1. [Seder Hadorot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seder_HaDoroth), Third Millennium, [Year 321](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46817&st=&pgnum=96&hilite=).</sup>

<sup>2. Ibid., Fourth Millennium, [Year 321](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46817&st=&pgnum=147).</sup>