# When did the plague of vermin stop?

Tags: plagues-makkos, va-eira

The plague of vermin or lice is not said to have stopped in the verses, ([Ex 8](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9869):12-15). When, if at all, did it stop?

Comment: comment not an answer because this is not my answer, just a reference to another answer. http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/8466/1362 look at the highlighted quote from the Kehot Chumash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit **Danno** for pointing out this answer, by **Menachem**, that cites Rashi on Exodus 7:25, as well as unspecified midrashim: [Moshe's age and the timeline of the exodus](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8438/moshes-age-and-the-timeline-of-the-exodus/8466#8466)

The midrash can be found in Exodus Rabah 9:12 as an argument between R' Yehudah and R' Nehemiah. One says that warning of each plague lasted 24 days, and the plague itself lasted 7 days. The other says that the warning lasted 7 days and the plague itself lasted 24.

The Etz Yosef on that midrash provides more detailed information, including other sources, as to the consensus that events surrounding each plague lasted 1 month, with the exception of the plague of the firstborn.