# Timeline of the 10 plagues in exodus?

Tags: history, plagues-makkos

Do we have a chronological timeline (with years) of the 10 plagues?
I'm trying to recreate a full timeline of the הגדה של פסח for the upcoming holiday, going from the arrival of Jacob and his family to the splitting of the Yam Suf (red sea).

Comment: Probably starting around a year before the Exodus.

Comment: Hello Que20, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for the interesting question! If you haven’t done so already, you should take a look at the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour). 
I hope you'll look around and find other Q&A of interest and stay learning with us.

Comment: See also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8438

Comment: You're trying in general to create a full timeline but in this question seek only the plagues' timeline. Right?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/36570/472

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, and thank you for having corrected and edited my question.
@msh210 That's exactly what I'm doing: a full timeline. I did found informations but it's harder than I thought... I can't easily put historical markers in שְׁמוֹת (Burning bush episode), וָאֵרָא and בֹּא (the 10 plagues) then בְּשַׁלַּח (splitting of the red sea).